# Equivalent of setInterval in python

Tags: python, multithreading, setinterval

I have recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177439/postponing-functions-in-python) about how to postpone execution of a function in Python (kind of equivalent to Javascript `setTimeout`) and it turns out to be a simple task using `threading.Timer` (well, simple as long as the function does not share state with other code, but that would create problems in any event-driven environment).

Now I am trying to do better and emulate `setInterval`. For those who are not familiar with Javascript, `setInterval` allows to repeat a call to a function every x seconds, without blocking the execution of other code. I have created this example decorator:

```
import time, threading

def setInterval(interval, times = -1):
    # This will be the actual decorator,
    # with fixed interval and times parameter
    def outer_wrap(function):
        # This will be the function to be
        # called
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            # This is another function to be executed
            # in a different thread to simulate setInterval
            def inner_wrap():
                i = 0
                while i != times:
                    time.sleep(interval)
                    function(*args, **kwargs)
                    i += 1
            threading.Timer(0, inner_wrap).start()
        return wrap
    return outer_wrap
```

to be used as follows

```
@setInterval(1, 3)
def foo(a):
    print(a)

foo('bar')
# Will print 'bar' 3 times with 1 second delays
```

and it seems to me it is working fine. My problem is that

- it seems overly complicated, and I fear I may have missed a simpler/better mechanism
- the decorator can be called without the second parameter, in which case it will go on forever. When I say foreover, I mean **forever** - even calling `sys.exit()` from the main thread will not stop it, nor will hitting `Ctrl+c`. The only way to stop it is to kill python process from the outside. I would like to be able to send a signal from the main thread that would stop the callback. But I am a beginner with threads - how can I communicate between them?

**EDIT** In case anyone wonders, this is the final version of the decorator, thanks to the help of jd

```
import threading

def setInterval(interval, times = -1):
    # This will be the actual decorator,
    # with fixed interval and times parameter
    def outer_wrap(function):
        # This will be the function to be
        # called
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            stop = threading.Event()

            # This is another function to be executed
            # in a different thread to simulate setInterval
            def inner_wrap():
                i = 0
                while i != times and not stop.isSet():
                    stop.wait(interval)
                    function(*args, **kwargs)
                    i += 1

            t = threading.Timer(0, inner_wrap)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            return stop
        return wrap
    return outer_wrap
```

It can be used with a fixed amount of repetitions as above

```
@setInterval(1, 3)
def foo(a):
    print(a)

foo('bar')
# Will print 'bar' 3 times with 1 second delays
```

or can be left to run until it receives a stop signal

```
import time

@setInterval(1)
def foo(a):
    print(a)

stopper = foo('bar')

time.sleep(5)
stopper.set()
# It will stop here, after printing 'bar' 5 times.
```

Comment: I was looking over your code and I was a bit confused because I didn't see what causes the loop to actually stop. It seemed to me that this would actually result in a loop that calls `function` slowly until `stopper.set()` is called, at which point the loop would suddenly accelerate! I checked, and indeed, if you add another `time.sleep(5)` after `stopper.set()` in the example above, that's exactly what happens. You need to incorporate some logic to make sure that the loop stops once `stop.is_set()` is true -- e.g. `while i != times and not stop.is_set():`

Comment: You are right, I misinterpreted one paragraph in the doc about the `wait()` method, and I did not catch the problem with my tests. I will now correct the code.

Comment: I've posted the answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177439/postponing-functions-in-python) that demonstrates [how to emulate Javascript's `setInterval()` without threads in Tkinter, Gtk, Twisted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279)

Comment: Here's a [simple Event-based `call_repeatedly(interval, func, *args)` implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22498708/4279)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your solution looks fine to me.

There are several ways to communicate with threads. To order a thread to stop, you can use `threading.Event()`, which has a `wait()` method that you can use instead of `time.sleep()`.

```
stop_event = threading.Event()
...
stop_event.wait(1.)
if stop_event.isSet():
    return
...
```

For your thread to exit when the program is terminated, set its `daemon` attribute to `True` before calling `start()`. This applies to `Timer()` objects as well because they subclass `threading.Thread`. See http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

Comment: Wonderful! I was able to remove the dependency on the time module and to manage to get communication. Now the callback can easily be stopped. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe these are the easiest setInterval equivalent in python:

```
 import threading

 def set_interval(func, sec):
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec) 
        func()  
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t
```

Comment: The reference to the inner timers gets lost. If the first Timer has already fired, there is no reference to stop the subsequent ones.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit simpler is to use recursive calls to Timer:

```
from threading import Timer
import atexit

class Repeat(object):

    count = 0
    @staticmethod
    def repeat(rep, delay, func):
        "repeat func rep times with a delay given in seconds"

        if Repeat.count < rep:
            # call func, you might want to add args here
            func()
            Repeat.count += 1
            # setup a timer which calls repeat recursively
            # again, if you need args for func, you have to add them here
            timer = Timer(delay, Repeat.repeat, (rep, delay, func))
            # register timer.cancel to stop the timer when you exit the interpreter
            atexit.register(timer.cancel)
            timer.start()

def foo():
    print "bar"

Repeat.repeat(3,2,foo)
```

`atexit` allows to signal stopping with CTRL-C.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I already accepted jd's answer. In any case I prefer sleeping instead of recursively creating new Timers - by the way, would this spawn infintely many threads, or are the threads killed when the function returns, even though a thread they created is still open?

Comment: AFAIK it will spawn rep-many threads, they all terminate when the last Timer has finished.

Comment: This may be annoying if you want to repeat the function thousands of times, or even forever. Thank you for your input anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

this class Interval

```
class ali:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sure = True;

    def aliv(self,func,san):
        print "ali naber";
        self.setInterVal(func, san);

    def setInterVal(self,func, san):

        # istenilen saniye veya dakika aralığında program calışır. 
        def func_Calistir():

            func(func,san);  #calışıcak fonksiyon.
        self.t = threading.Timer(san, func_Calistir)
        self.t.start()
        return self.t


a = ali();
a.setInterVal(a.aliv,5);
```