# threading.Timer - repeat function every 'n' seconds

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, python-multithreading

I want to fire off a function every 0.5 seconds and be able to start and stop and reset the timer. I'm not too knowledgeable of how Python threads work and am having difficulties with the python timer.

However, I keep getting `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once` when I execute `threading.timer.start()` twice. Is there a work around for this? I tried applying `threading.timer.cancel()` before each start.

Pseudo code:

```
t=threading.timer(0.5,function)
while True:
    t.cancel()
    t.start()
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The best way is to start the timer thread once. Inside your timer thread you'd code the following

```
class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(0.5):
            print("my thread")
            # call a function
```

In the code that started the timer, you can then `set` the stopped event to stop the timer.

```
stopFlag = Event()
thread = MyThread(stopFlag)
thread.start()
# this will stop the timer
stopFlag.set()
```

Comment: thank you for the response :) However, what if I need to stop the timer while it is sleeping for instance at the 0.3 second?

Comment: Then it will finish it's sleep and stop afterwards. There is no way to _forcibly_ suspend a thread in python. This is a design decision made by the python developers. However the net result will be the same. You thread will still run (sleep) for a short while, but it will not perform your function.

Comment: Well, actually, if you want to be able to stop the timer thread immediately, just use a `threading.Event` and `wait` instead of `sleep`. Then, to wake it up, just set the event. You don't even need the `self.stopped` then because you just check the event flag.

Comment: Will this work? Which thread will fire the events? Would you use the main loop to sleep(0.5) and then wakeup the processing thread?

Comment: The event would be used strictly to interrupt the timer thread. Normally, the `event.wait` would just timeout and act like a sleep, but if you wanted to stop (or otherwise interrupt the thread) you'd set the thread's event and it would wake up immediately.

Comment: Then it will not do what the OP wants it to do. It can only be used to wakeup a thread, not to stop it.

Comment: @HansThen: you can interrupt the `event.wait()` call that breaks the loop that exits the thread's `.run()` method that stops the thread. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16368571/4279).

Comment: I have updated my answer to use event.wait(). Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: just a question, how can I restart the thread after that? calling `thread.start()` gives me `threads can only be started once`

Answer (score 66):

Improving a little on [Hans Then's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12435256/8589122), we can just subclass the Timer function. The following becomes our **entire** "repeat timer" code, and it can be used as a drop-in replacement for threading.Timer with all the same arguments:

```
from threading import Timer

class RepeatTimer(Timer):
    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

Usage example:

```
def dummyfn(msg="foo"):
    print(msg)

timer = RepeatTimer(1, dummyfn)
timer.start()
time.sleep(5)
timer.cancel()
```

produces the following output:

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

and

```
timer = RepeatTimer(1, dummyfn, args=("bar",))
timer.start()
time.sleep(5)
timer.cancel()
```

produces

```
bar
bar
bar
bar
```

Comment: Will this approach allow me to start/cancel/start/cancel the timer thread?

Comment: No. While this approach allows you to do anything you would with an ordinary Timer, you can't do that with an ordinary Timer. Since start/cancel is related to the underlying thread, if you try to .start() a thread which has previously been .cancel()'ed then you will get an exception, `RuntimeError: threads can only be started once`.

Comment: Really elegant solution! Odd that they didn't just include a class that does this.

Comment: this solution is very impressive, but I struggled to understand how it was designed from simply reading the [Python3 threading Timer interface documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). The answer appears to build on knowing the implementation by going into the `threading.py` module itself.

Comment: Really nice solution! ...there's actually no need for `dummyfn` if you only want to call print... `RepeatTimer(1, print, args=("my message",))` does the job equally well!

Comment: this works for me !  i'm using an endless for-loop to read stdout and so i needed a way to also display a time indication every second (also when the for-loop halts because no stdout) .. this simple code does it .. in my case i start the timer at the beginning of my script and it keeps running, i don't even need cancel.

Answer (score 38):

From [Equivalent of setInterval in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5179467/4279):

```
import threading

def setInterval(interval):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            stopped = threading.Event()

            def loop(): # executed in another thread
                while not stopped.wait(interval): # until stopped
                    function(*args, **kwargs)

            t = threading.Thread(target=loop)
            t.daemon = True # stop if the program exits
            t.start()
            return stopped
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Usage:

```
@setInterval(.5)
def function():
    "..."

stop = function() # start timer, the first call is in .5 seconds
stop.set() # stop the loop
stop = function() # start new timer
# ...
stop.set()
```

Or here's [the same functionality but as a standalone function instead of a decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22498708/4279):

```
cancel_future_calls = call_repeatedly(60, print, "Hello, World")
# ...
cancel_future_calls()
```

[Here's how to do it without using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279).

Comment: how would you change the interval when using a decorator? say i want to change .5s at runtime to 1 second or whatever?

Comment: @lightxx: just use `@setInterval(1)`.

Comment: hm. so either I'm a bit slow or you misunderstood me. I meant at runtime. I know i can change the decorator in the source code any time. what, for example, i had three functions, each decorated with a @setInterval(n). now at runtime i want to change the interval of function 2 but leave functions 1 and 3 alone.

Comment: @lightxx: you could use different interface e.g., `stop = repeat(every=second, call=your_function); ...; stop()`.

Comment: @lightxx: here's a non-decorator [`stop = call_repeatedly(interval, your_function); ...; stop()` implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22498708/4279)

Answer (score 35):

Using timer threads-

```
from threading import Timer,Thread,Event


class perpetualTimer():

   def __init__(self,t,hFunction):
      self.t=t
      self.hFunction = hFunction
      self.thread = Timer(self.t,self.handle_function)

   def handle_function(self):
      self.hFunction()
      self.thread = Timer(self.t,self.handle_function)
      self.thread.start()

   def start(self):
      self.thread.start()

   def cancel(self):
      self.thread.cancel()

def printer():
    print 'ipsem lorem'

t = perpetualTimer(5,printer)
t.start()
```

this can be stopped by `t.cancel()`

Comment: I believe this code has a bug in the `cancel` method. When this is called, the thread is either 1) not running or 2) running. In 1) we are waiting to run the function, so cancel will work fine. in 2) we are currently running, so cancel will have no effect on the current execution. furthermore, the current execution reschedules itself so it will not have an effect in future etiher.

Comment: This code creates a new thread every time the timer runs down. This is a colossal waste as compared to the accepted answer.

Comment: This solution should be avoided, for the reason mentioned above: it creates a new thread every time

Answer (score 19):

In the interest of providing a correct answer using Timer as the OP requested, I'll improve upon [swapnil jariwala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds/24488061#24488061):

```
from threading import Timer


class InfiniteTimer():
    """A Timer class that does not stop, unless you want it to."""

    def __init__(self, seconds, target):
        self._should_continue = False
        self.is_running = False
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.target = target
        self.thread = None

    def _handle_target(self):
        self.is_running = True
        self.target()
        self.is_running = False
        self._start_timer()

    def _start_timer(self):
        if self._should_continue: # Code could have been running when cancel was called.
            self.thread = Timer(self.seconds, self._handle_target)
            self.thread.start()

    def start(self):
        if not self._should_continue and not self.is_running:
            self._should_continue = True
            self._start_timer()
        else:
            print("Timer already started or running, please wait if you're restarting.")

    def cancel(self):
        if self.thread is not None:
            self._should_continue = False # Just in case thread is running and cancel fails.
            self.thread.cancel()
        else:
            print("Timer never started or failed to initialize.")


def tick():
    print('ipsem lorem')

# Example Usage
t = InfiniteTimer(0.5, tick)
t.start()
```

Comment: This is a really good framework, but does result in an ever increasing number of _thread.lock objects for each iteration of _start_timer

Answer (score 5):

I have changed some code in swapnil-jariwala code to make a little console clock.

```
from threading import Timer, Thread, Event
from datetime import datetime

class PT():

    def __init__(self, t, hFunction):
        self.t = t
        self.hFunction = hFunction
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)

    def handle_function(self):
        self.hFunction()
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)
        self.thread.start()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

def printer():
    tempo = datetime.today()
    h,m,s = tempo.hour, tempo.minute, tempo.second
    print(f"{h}:{m}:{s}")


t = PT(1, printer)
t.start()
```

> OUTPUT

```
>>> 11:39:11
11:39:12
11:39:13
11:39:14
11:39:15
11:39:16
...
```

## Timer with a tkinter Graphic interface

This code puts the clock timer in a little window with tkinter

```
from threading import Timer, Thread, Event
from datetime import datetime
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
lab = tk.Label(app, text="Timer will start in a sec")
lab.pack()


class perpetualTimer():

    def __init__(self, t, hFunction):
        self.t = t
        self.hFunction = hFunction
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)

    def handle_function(self):
        self.hFunction()
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)
        self.thread.start()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def cancel(self):
        self.thread.cancel()


def printer():
    tempo = datetime.today()
    clock = "{}:{}:{}".format(tempo.hour, tempo.minute, tempo.second)
    try:
        lab['text'] = clock
    except RuntimeError:
        exit()


t = perpetualTimer(1, printer)
t.start()
app.mainloop()
```

## An example of flashcards game (sort of)

```
from threading import Timer, Thread, Event
from datetime import datetime


class perpetualTimer():

    def __init__(self, t, hFunction):
        self.t = t
        self.hFunction = hFunction
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)

    def handle_function(self):
        self.hFunction()
        self.thread = Timer(self.t, self.handle_function)
        self.thread.start()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def cancel(self):
        self.thread.cancel()


x = datetime.today()
start = x.second


def printer():
    global questions, counter, start
    x = datetime.today()
    tempo = x.second
    if tempo - 3 > start:
        show_ans()
    #print("\n{}:{}:{}".format(tempo.hour, tempo.minute, tempo.second), end="")
    print()
    print("-" + questions[counter])
    counter += 1
    if counter == len(answers):
        counter = 0


def show_ans():
    global answers, c2
    print("It is {}".format(answers[c2]))
    c2 += 1
    if c2 == len(answers):
        c2 = 0


questions = ["What is the capital of Italy?",
             "What is the capital of France?",
             "What is the capital of England?",
             "What is the capital of Spain?"]

answers = "Rome", "Paris", "London", "Madrid"

counter = 0
c2 = 0
print("Get ready to answer")
t = perpetualTimer(3, printer)
t.start()
```

output:

```
Get ready to answer
>>> 
-What is the capital of Italy?
It is Rome

-What is the capital of France?
It is Paris

-What is the capital of England?
...
```

Comment: if hFunction is blocking wouldn't this add some delay to subsequent starting times? Maybe you could swap the lines round so that handle_function starts timer first and then calls hFunction?

Answer (score 3):

I had to do this for a project. What I ended up doing was start a separate thread for the function

```
t = threading.Thread(target =heartbeat, args=(worker,))
t.start()
```

****heartbeat is my function, worker is one of my arguments****

inside of my heartbeat function:

```
def heartbeat(worker):

    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        #all of my code
```

So when I start the thread the function will repeatedly wait 5 seconds, run all of my code, and do that indefinitely. If you want to kill the process just kill the thread.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late but here are my two cents:

You can reuse the `threading.Timer` object by calling its `.run()` method repeatedly, like so:

```py
class SomeClassThatNeedsATimer:
    def __init__(...):
        self.timer = threading.Timer(interval, self.on_timer)
        self.timer.start()

    def on_timer(self):
        print('On timer')
        self.timer.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above great answers using Threads, in case you have to use your main thread or prefer an async approach - I wrapped a short class around [aio_timers](https://pypi.org/project/aio-timers/) Timer class (to enable repeating)

```
import asyncio
from aio_timers import Timer

class RepeatingAsyncTimer():
    def __init__(self, interval, cb, *args, **kwargs):
        self.interval = interval
        self.cb = cb
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.aio_timer = None
        self.start_timer()
    
    def start_timer(self):
        self.aio_timer = Timer(delay=self.interval, 
                               callback=self.cb_wrapper, 
                               callback_args=self.args, 
                               callback_kwargs=self.kwargs
                              )
    
    def cb_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.cb(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_timer()


from time import time
def cb(timer_name):
    print(timer_name, time())

print(f'clock starts at: {time()}')
timer_1 = RepeatingAsyncTimer(interval=5, cb=cb, timer_name='timer_1')
timer_2 = RepeatingAsyncTimer(interval=10, cb=cb, timer_name='timer_2')
```

clock starts at: 16024388**40**.9690785

timer_**1** 16024388**45**.980087

timer_**2** 16024388**50**.9806316

timer_**1** 16024388**50**.9808934

timer_**1** 16024388**55**.9863033

timer_**2** 16024388**60**.9868324

timer_**1** 16024388**60**.9876585

Comment: splendid. :) better than all others. and precise.

Comment: @mork why did you import asyncio ?

Comment: @eranotzap I think it was needed at the time, for the underlying lib.

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Timer
def TaskManager():
    #do stuff
    t = Timer( 1, TaskManager )
    t.start()

TaskManager()
```

Here is small sample, it will help beter understanding how it runs.
function taskManager() at the end create delayed function call to it self.

Try to change "dalay" variable and you will able to see difference

```
from threading import Timer, _sleep

# ------------------------------------------
DATA = []
dalay = 0.25 # sec
counter = 0
allow_run = True
FIFO = True

def taskManager():

    global counter, DATA, delay, allow_run
    counter += 1

    if len(DATA) > 0:
        if FIFO:
            print("["+str(counter)+"] new data: ["+str(DATA.pop(0))+"]")
        else:
            print("["+str(counter)+"] new data: ["+str(DATA.pop())+"]")

    else:
        print("["+str(counter)+"] no data")

    if allow_run:
        #delayed method/function call to it self
        t = Timer( dalay, taskManager )
        t.start()

    else:
        print(" END task-manager: disabled")

# ------------------------------------------
def main():

    DATA.append("data from main(): 0")
    _sleep(2)
    DATA.append("data from main(): 1")
    _sleep(2)


# ------------------------------------------
print(" START task-manager:")
taskManager()

_sleep(2)
DATA.append("first data")

_sleep(2)
DATA.append("second data")

print(" START main():")
main()
print(" END main():")

_sleep(2)
DATA.append("last data")

allow_run = False
```

Comment: can you also tell a little more as to why this works?

Comment: your example was a little confusing, the first codeblock was all you needed to say.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a class that works as a timer.

I leave the link here in case anyone needs it:
https://github.com/ivanhalencp/python/tree/master/xTimer

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I like right2clicky's answer, especially in that it doesn't require a Thread to be torn down and a new one created every time the Timer ticks. In addition, it's an easy override to create a class with a timer callback that gets called periodically. That's my normal use case:

```
class MyClass(RepeatTimer):
    def __init__(self, period):
        super().__init__(period, self.on_timer)

    def on_timer(self):
        print("Tick")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mc = MyClass(1)
    mc.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    mc.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate implementation using function instead of class. Inspired by @Andrew Wilkins above.

Because wait is more accurate than sleep ( it takes function runtime into account ):

```
import threading

PING_ON = threading.Event()

def ping():
  while not PING_ON.wait(1):
    print("my thread %s" % str(threading.current_thread().ident))

t = threading.Thread(target=ping)
t.start()

sleep(5)
PING_ON.set()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with another solution with SingleTon class. Please tell me if any memory leakage is here.

```
import time,threading

class Singleton:
  __instance = None
  sleepTime = 1
  executeThread = False

  def __init__(self):
     if Singleton.__instance != None:
        raise Exception("This class is a singleton!")
     else:
        Singleton.__instance = self

  @staticmethod
  def getInstance():
     if Singleton.__instance == None:
        Singleton()
     return Singleton.__instance


  def startThread(self):
     self.executeThread = True
     self.threadNew = threading.Thread(target=self.foo_target)
     self.threadNew.start()
     print('doing other things...')


  def stopThread(self):
     print("Killing Thread ")
     self.executeThread = False
     self.threadNew.join()
     print(self.threadNew)


  def foo(self):
     print("Hello in " + str(self.sleepTime) + " seconds")


  def foo_target(self):
     while self.executeThread:
        self.foo()
        print(self.threadNew)
        time.sleep(self.sleepTime)

        if not self.executeThread:
           break


sClass = Singleton()
sClass.startThread()
time.sleep(5)
sClass.getInstance().stopThread()

sClass.getInstance().sleepTime = 2
sClass.startThread()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of providing a correct answer using Timer as the OP requested, I'll improve upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450617/20750754

```
from threading import Timer


class InfiniteTimer():
  """A Timer class that does not stop, unless you want it to."""

  def __init__(self, seconds, target, args=[], kwargs=dict()):
    self._should_continue = False
    self.is_running = False
    self.seconds = seconds
    self.target = target
    self.args = args
    self.kwargs = kwargs
    self.thread = None

  def _handle_target(self):
    self.is_running = True
    self.target(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    self.is_running = False
    self._start_timer()

  def _start_timer(self):
    if self._should_continue:  # Code could have been running when cancel was called.
      self.thread = Timer(
        self.seconds,
        self._handle_target,
      )
      self.thread.start()

  def start(self):
    if not self._should_continue and not self.is_running:
      self._should_continue = True
      self._start_timer()
    else:
      print(
        "Timer already started or running, please wait if you're restarting.")

  def cancel(self):
    if self.thread is not None:
      self._should_continue = False  # Just in case thread is running and cancel fails.
      self.thread.cancel()
    else:
      print("Timer never started or failed to initialize.")


def tick(i):
  print('ipsem lorem', i)


# Example Usage
t = InfiniteTimer(0.5, tick, kwargs=dict(i="i"))
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code for running the timer continuously. Just create a new timer upon exhaustion and call the same function. Not the best way to do it but can be done like this as well.

```
import threading
import time


class ContinousTimer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.timer = None

    def run(self, msg='abc'):
        print(msg)

        self.timer = threading.Timer(interval=2, function=self.run, args=(msg, ))
        self.timer.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = ContinousTimer()
    try:
        t.run(msg="Hello")
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Cancel Timer
        t.timer.cancel()
```