# Python Threading Timer works on Windows but not Linux

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, timer

I've created a Thread that execute every 60 seconds, just like a Timer or a SetInterval, based on this: [Python threading.timer - repeat function every 'n' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)

It always worked fine on Windows, but now I have to execute this on Linux (Fedora and Ubuntu, for now) and it's just don't work!

I can't wonder why, because it doesn't return any error. And my Shot function works fine out of the Thread.

Here is my code:

```
class ShotAllTheTime(Thread):
    """
        Thread principal que invoca as operações do Client
    """
    def __init__(self, event, time_between_shots = 60, *args, **kwargs):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.finished = event
        self.time_between_shots = time_between_shots
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def cancel(self):
        #Termina a thread.
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.wait(self.time_between_shots):
            Shot()
```

This is how I call the ShotAllTheTime Thread:

```
def main()
    stop_shots = Event()
    MyThread = ShotAllTheTime(stop_shots)
    MyThread.start()
    while 1:
        entrada = raw_input("\nEnter 'exit' to exit:")
        if entrada == 'exit':
            stop_shots.set()
            break

    sys.exit()

main()
```

Comment: 'does not work' - do you mean that side effects inside Shot() do not occur in the main thread?

Comment: I'm on linux and your code runs just fine: I've just changed `Shot()` by `print 'shot'` so the problem should be on the `Shot` object

Comment: @xndrme how did you called the Thread? I've edited the question and put how I am calling mine. Is it printing 'shot' every 60 seconds?

Comment: This is my script: http://pastebin.com/NzPfHHgb and this is the output: http://pastebin.com/hQmEdB0a