# Python end parent process from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, multiprocessing

My aim is to create a new process which will take a number as input from user in a loop and display the square of it. If the user doesn't enter a number for 10 seconds, the process should end (not the main process). I'm using `threading.Timer` with `multiprocessing`.

**Tried Code**

```
from threading import Timer
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def foo(stdin):
    while True:
        t = Timer(10, exit, ())
        t.start()
        print 'Enter a No. in 10 Secs: ',
        num = int(stdin.readline())
        t.cancel()
        print 'Square of', num, 'is', num*num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    newstdin = os.fdopen(os.dup(sys.stdin.fileno()))
    proc1 = mp.Process(target = foo, args = (newstdin, ))
    proc1.start()
    proc1.join()
    print "Exit"
    newstdin.close()
```

But it's not working. Instead of `exit` I tried with `sys.exit`, Taken `proc1` as `global` and tried `proc1.terminate`, But still no solution.

Comment: Using `threading.Timer` with `multiprocessing.Process` might not be a happy couple, try not mix threads and processes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297627/why-no-timer-class-in-pythons-multiprocessing-module

Comment: @d6bels I've read it at some places. But there is no other way to achieve what I want.

Comment: Well as long as you only use the timer in the subprocess I don't think this is so bad ;-)

Comment: @d6bels Initially I was planning with `multiprocessing` only and no use of `threading`. For the above task, I tried `scheduler` with `sched` a lot. But not seemed to work for me. So `Timer`. :-)

Comment: It looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096): if you want *"raw_input with timeout"* then you could [use `select()` or `msvcrt.kbhit()` depending on your system](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335507/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced `exit` with `os._exit` and it's working as expected.

```
t = Timer(10, os._exit, [0])
```

`os._exit` takes exactly `1 argument`, hence we have to mention `0` in a list. (In `threading.Timer` to pass arguments to the function, the arguments should be in a `list`.)