# Synchronizing timed parallel processes at different frequencies

Tags: python, timer, multiprocessing, synchronization

I'm trying to simulate different tasks running in parallel in Python, and each parallel process is run at different frequencies (e.g. 200 Hz, 100 Hz and 50 Hz). I used code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25297627/why-no-timer-class-in-pythons-multiprocessing-module) to make a Timer class to run these processes in "Real-Time", but the processes de-synchronize over time (e.i., three 200 Hz tasks can sometimes run in between two 100 Hz tasks).

To synchronize my processes I make tick counters in their shared memory. Every iteration of the 200 Hz process increments a counter, then waits for it to be reset to 0 when the counter reaches 2, while every iteration of 100 Hz process waits for that counter to reach 2 before resetting it. Same thing for the 50 Hz process, but with another counter. I use a while/pass method for the waiting.

Here is the code :

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Event, Value
import time

# Add Timer class for multiprocessing
class Timer(Process):
    def __init__(self, interval, iteration, function, args=[], kwargs={}):
        super(Timer, self).__init__()
        self.interval = interval
        self.iteration = iteration
        self.iterationLeft = self.iteration
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.finished = Event()

    def cancel(self):
        """Stop the timer if it hasn't finished yet"""
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        startTimeProcess = time.perf_counter()
        while self.iterationLeft > 0:
            startTimePeriod = time.perf_counter()
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            # print(self.interval-(time.clock() - startTimePeriod))
            self.finished.wait(self.interval-(time.perf_counter() - startTimePeriod))
            self.iterationLeft -= 1
        print(f'Process finished in {round(time.perf_counter()-startTimeProcess, 5)} seconds')


def func0(id, freq, tick_p1):
    # Wait for 2 runs of Process 1 (tick_p1)
    while tick_p1.value < 2:
        pass
    tick_p1.value = 0   # Reset tick_p1

    # Add fake computational time depending on the frequency of the process
    print(f'id: {id} at {freq} Hz') 
    if freq == 400:
        time.sleep(0.002)
    elif freq == 200:
        time.sleep(0.003)
    elif freq == 100:
        time.sleep(0.007)
    elif freq == 50:
        time.sleep(0.015)



def func1(id, freq, tick_p1, tick_p2):
    # Wait for tick_p1 to have been reset by Process0
    while tick_p1.value >= 2:
        pass
    # Wait for 2 runs of Process 2 (tick_p2)
    while tick_p2.value < 2:
        pass
    tick_p2.value = 0   # Reset tick_p2

    # Add fake computational time depending on the frequency of the process
    print(f'id: {id} at {freq} Hz') 
    if freq == 400:
        time.sleep(0.002)
    elif freq == 200:
        time.sleep(0.003)
    elif freq == 100:
        time.sleep(0.007)
    elif freq == 50:
        time.sleep(0.015)

    # Increment tick_p1
    tick_p1.value += 1


def func2(id, freq, tick_p2):
    # Wait for tick_p2 to have been reset by Process1
    while tick_p2.value >= 2:
        pass

    # Add fake computational time depending on the frequency of the process
    print(f'id: {id} at {freq} Hz') 
    if freq == 400:
        time.sleep(0.002)
    elif freq == 200:
        time.sleep(0.003)
    elif freq == 100:
        time.sleep(0.007)
    elif freq == 50:
        time.sleep(0.015)

    # Increment tick_p2
    tick_p2.value += 1



if __name__ == '__main__':
    freqs = [50,100,200]
    # freqs = [0.25,0.5,1]
    Tf = 10

    tick_p1 = Value('i', 1)
    tick_p2 = Value('i', 1)  

    processes = []
    p0 = Timer(interval=1/freqs[0], iteration=round(Tf*freqs[0]), function = func0, args=(0,freqs[0], tick_p1))
    p1 = Timer(interval=1/freqs[1], iteration=round(Tf*freqs[1]), function = func1, args=(1,freqs[1], tick_p1, tick_p2))
    p2 = Timer(interval=1/freqs[2], iteration=round(Tf*freqs[2]), function = func2, args=(2,freqs[2], tick_p2))
    processes.append(p0)
    processes.append(p1)
    processes.append(p2)

    start = time.perf_counter()
    for process in processes:
        process.start()   

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    finish = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'Finished in {round(finish-start, 5)} seconds')
```

As you can see, I've added sleep time within the processes, to simulate computational time. When I remove the print commands in the processes, the script requires 10.2 seconds of runtime to simulate 10 seconds of "real-time" calculations (2% increase, which is acceptable).

My question is, is this the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Is there a better/faster way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a cleaner way to do this, but I'm still open to other suggestions.

Basically, instead of waiting for the moment to execute the next iteration, I've created a scheduler that flags when to run a cycle on each process (using shared Values).

There is a fast processes (lets say `p2` running at 400 Hz) and all other processes must be a slower multiple of the frequency (lets say `p1` and `p0` 200 and 100 Hz).

Instead of waiting for the right moment to raise execution flag (with `wait()` or `sleep()`), the scheduler loops with a `while` loop and checks if a period of p2 has ended. If the condition is met, it raised `p2Flag` and restart the period. Each process has its own flag, and the slower processes' flags get raised according to a counter which is incremented every period of `p2`. If 2 timesteps of `p2` have run since the last time `p1` was called, this scheduler will "wait" for `p1` to be completed before raising `p2`'s and `p1`'s flag.

It's a bit complicated, but this ensures slower machines will obtain the same results as machines who can run this in "real-time".

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
import time

def func0(id, freq, endFlag, p0Flag, runIdx, Ts):
    while (endFlag.value == 0):
        if (p0Flag.value == 1):
            t = round(runIdx.value*Ts, 4)

            # Add fake computational time depending on the frequency of the process
            # print(f'id: {id} at {freq} Hz at {t}s') 
            if freq == 400:
                time.sleep(0.002)
            elif freq == 200:
                time.sleep(0.003)
            elif freq == 100:
                time.sleep(0.007)
            elif freq == 50:
                time.sleep(0.015)

            # Lower flag to confirm completion of cycle
            p0Flag.value = 0


def func1(id, freq, endFlag, p1Flag, runIdx, Ts):
    while (endFlag.value == 0):
        if (p1Flag.value == 1):
            t = round(runIdx.value*Ts, 4)

            # Add fake computational time depending on the frequency of the process
            # print(f'id: {id} at {freq} Hz at {t}s') 
            if freq == 400:
                time.sleep(0.002)
            elif freq == 200:
                time.sleep(0.003)
            elif freq == 100:
                time.sleep(0.007)
            elif freq == 50:
                time.sleep(0.015)

            # Lower flag to confirm completion of cycle
            p1Flag.value = 0


def func2(id, freq, endFlag, p2Flag, runIdx, Ts):
    while (endFlag.value == 0):
        if (p2Flag.value == 1):
            t = round(runIdx.value*Ts, 4)

            # Add fake computational time depending on the frequency of the process
            # print(f'id: {id} at {freq} Hz at {t}s') 
            if freq == 500:
                time.sleep(0.0015)
            elif freq == 400:
                time.sleep(0.002)
            elif freq == 200:
                time.sleep(0.003)
            elif freq == 100:
                time.sleep(0.007)
            elif freq == 50:
                time.sleep(0.015)

            # Update time for next iteration
            runIdx.value += 1
            # Lower flag to confirm completion of cycle
            p2Flag.value = 0



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Set frequencies of processes
    # Last value of freqs is the fastest one, for process p2
    freqs = [50,100,200]    # Hz
    freqs = [100,200,400]   # Hz
    # freqs = [0.25,0.5,1]  # Hz
    Tf = 10
    Ts = round(1/freqs[-1], 4)

    # Create shared values for time index (runIdx)
    # Various flags to trigger the execution of the code in each process (p0Flag, ...)
    # A flag to en all processes
    runIdx = Value('I',0)
    p0Flag = Value('b', 0)
    p1Flag = Value('b', 0)
    p2Flag = Value('b', 0)
    endFlag = Value('b', 0)

    # How many times the fastest process has to run before flagging the slower processes
    p0_counter_exe = freqs[-1]/freqs[0]
    p1_counter_exe = freqs[-1]/freqs[1]

    if (not(freqs[-1] % freqs[0] == 0) or not(freqs[-1] % freqs[1] == 0)):
        raise Exception("Update rates for processes must be a multiple of the dynamic's update rate.")
    if (freqs[-1] < freqs[0]) or (freqs[-1] < freqs[1]):
        raise Exception("Dynamics update rate must be the fastest.")

    # p2 is at fastest frequency, p1 and p0 at lower frequencies
    p0 = Process(target=func0, args=(0, freqs[0], endFlag, p0Flag, runIdx, Ts))
    p1 = Process(target=func1, args=(1, freqs[1], endFlag, p1Flag, runIdx, Ts))
    p2 = Process(target=func2, args=(2, freqs[2], endFlag, p2Flag, runIdx, Ts))
    processes = []
    processes.append(p0)
    processes.append(p1)
    processes.append(p2)

    for process in processes:
        process.start()   
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # Start subprocesse's counters to execute directly at the first timestep
    p0_counter = p0_counter_exe
    p1_counter = p1_counter_exe

    # Scheduler
    #------------
    startTime  = time.perf_counter()
    periodEnd = time.perf_counter()
    while (runIdx.value*Ts < Tf):
        periodTime = time.perf_counter()-periodEnd
        do_p2 = False

        # Wait for new timestep AND completion of p2
        if (periodTime >= Ts and p2Flag.value == 0):

            # If p0 or p1 are expected to finish before the new timestep, wait for their completion
            # Depending on the situation, if slower processes have finished their cycle, make do_p2 True
            if (p1_counter == p1_counter_exe) and (p0_counter == p0_counter_exe):
                if (p1Flag.value == 0) and (p0Flag.value == 0):
                    do_p2 = True
            elif (p1_counter == p1_counter_exe):
                if (p1Flag.value == 0):
                    do_p2 = True
            elif (p0_counter == p0_counter_exe):
                if (p0Flag.value == 0):
                    do_p2 = True
            else:
                do_p2 = 1

            # If do_p2 is True, raise p2Flag for the p2 process
            if (do_p2):
                periodEnd = time.perf_counter()
                p2Flag.value = 1

                # If it's time to start a cycle for the slower processes, raise their flag and reset their counter
                if (p1_counter == p1_counter_exe):
                    p1Flag.value = 1
                    p1_counter = 0 
                if (p0_counter == p0_counter_exe):
                    p0Flag.value = 1
                    p0_counter = 0

                # Increment slower processes counter
                p1_counter += 1
                p0_counter += 1


    # Close all processes
    endFlag.value = 1

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    print(f'Finished in {round(time.perf_counter()-startTime, 5)} seconds')
    print(Ts*runIdx.value)
```