# Log value of variable every second in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I need to print the value of a variable every second or couple of seconds, while "at the same time" this variable is being modified. So I would be modifying this variable in my main function and I want something to print its value every second. Something like:

```
'''This is my main program'''

for i in range(very large number):

'''do something which modifies the value of 'var' '''
```

And somewhere else in the code:

```
'''Every second'''

print var
```

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds) but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for, or how I should use it.

What I need is reaaaly simple, there are no other threads, and I don't care about syncing anything, or when in the main function the value is printed.

Comment: If you have no threads that paralelize the work (Modify var and print it's value) why you need to wait 1 second to print?

Comment: You can't do such things without using multithreading or multiprocessing or asynchronous (like gevent or tornado) approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use threading to print var each second.

try this example:

import threading

```
var = 5


def printit():
  global var
  threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
  print "Hello, World!", var

printit()

import time

for i in range(1000000):
    time.sleep(2)
    var = i
```

Comment: Both answers work, but this is the easiest. I just had to add a flag "done" so that when the other part finishes, this function stops. Otherwise it keeps running forever!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the question/answer you pointed to is what you need:

```
import threading import time

interesting = 0

class MonitorThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        global interesting
        while(1):
            print interesting
            time.sleep(1)

MonitorThread().start()

for interesting in range(2000000):
    time.sleep(1)
```