# GameOver screen not appearing when i want - pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having a problem with finding a way to blit the GameOver screen at the right time. I made a platformer on pygame and i want the Game Over screen to appear after the animation of my character dying has occurred and when the enemy has had his attack animation. Right now it bypasses any animation and as soon as the collision detection between sprites is true, it says Game Over. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
def GameOver():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.blit(pygame.image.load("background0.jpg").convert(), (0,0))
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("elephant",60)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("GameOver", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((screen_width/2),(screen_height/2))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self,x,y):

        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.width=40
        self.height = 40
        self.speed=1
        self.s0 = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/s0.png")
        self.s1 = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/s1.png")
        self.s2 = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/s2.png")
        self.s3 = pygame.image.load("Images/Enemy/s3.png")
        self.attack = pygame.image.load("attack.png")
        self.RotatedAttack = pygame.transform.flip(self.attack ,True,False)
        self.rotateds0 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s0 ,True, False)
        self.rotateds1 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s1 ,True, False)
        self.rotateds2 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s2 ,True, False)
        self.rotateds3 = pygame.transform.flip(self.s3 ,True, False)

        self.collision = False
        self.collision1 = False

        self.TimeTarget=10

        self.TimeNum=0

        self.currentImage=0

    def move(self,player):

        if self.x > player.x:
            self.x -= self.speed
            if self.currentImage > 3:
                self.currentImage = 0
            if self.collision == True:

                if self.currentImage < 4:
                    #image of him attacking
                    self.currentImage = 8
                    SpearAttack.play(loops = 0, maxtime = 10)                

        elif self.x < player.x:
            self.x += self.speed
            if self.currentImage < 4:    
                self.currentImage = 4
            if self.collision == True:
                if player.y > 487:

                    if self.currentImage == 4 or 5 or 6 or 7:
                        #image of him attacking flipped
                        self.currentImage = 9
                        SpearAttack.play(loops = 0, maxtime = 10)
                        #Tried putting gameover here but it skips the animation

        if self.x < player.x:
            if self.x > player.x:
                if self.currentImage > 3:
                    self.currentImage = 0       

    def update(self,CollisionDetect,player,enemy2):

        self.TimeNum+=1
        if self.TimeNum == self.TimeTarget:

            if self.currentImage ==0:
                self.currentImage=1

            elif self.currentImage ==1:
                self.currentImage=2

            elif self.currentImage == 2:
                self.currentImage=3

            elif self.currentImage ==3:
                self.currentImage =0

            elif self.currentImage ==4:
                self.currentImage=5

            elif self.currentImage ==5:
                self.currentImage=6

            elif self.currentImage == 6:
                self.currentImage=7

            elif self.currentImage ==7:
                self.currentImage = 4

            self.TimeNum=0

        if self.currentImage==0:

            screen.blit(self.s0, (self.x,self.y))

        elif self.currentImage==1:
            screen.blit(self.s1, (self.x,self.y))

        elif self.currentImage==2:
            screen.blit(self.s2, (self.x,self.y))

        elif self.currentImage ==3:
            screen.blit(self.s3, (self.x,self.y))

        elif self.currentImage==4:
            screen.blit(self.rotateds0, (self.x,self.y))

        elif self.currentImage==5:
            screen.blit(self.rotateds1, (self.x,self.y))

        elif self.currentImage==6:
            screen.blit(self.rotateds2, (self.x,self.y))

        elif self.currentImage ==7:
            screen.blit(self.rotateds3, (self.x,self.y))

        elif self.currentImage ==8:
            screen.blit(self.attack, (self.x,self.y))
            #tried putting GameOver() here but it skips the blit.
        elif self.currentImage ==9:
            screen.blit(self.RotatedAttack, (self.x,self.y))

        self.collision = CollisionDetect(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height,player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height)
```

Comment: Either your Indentation in this post is incorrect or your program shouldn't run at all without having anything in the GameOver function (not even a pass)

Comment: put the code that calls game over on the main loop

Comment: you should use list with images and then you could blit it in one line `blit( images[currentImage], ...)` instead of all `if/else`

Comment: Literally man, I can't help you with this sea of messy code. Make a game state manager.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you have to delay the animation. It seems that pygame doesn't have a default animation queue, therefore you'll have to take care of it. There are a few things that could actually work:

- Using `time.sleep()` - this wont work however if the animation is part of the single thread, since the entire thread will be stopped (and the animation should freeze). Therefore I'll recommend the second option since it sounds more reasonable for me.
- Using the pygame timer `pygame.time.set_timer()`, which should be a thread and therefore not freeze the spear-animation. You'll have to send a gameover event which will then be caught inside your gameover function and reset the timer for that event to 0 (to stop the loop) once it's caught. https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#comment_pygame_time_set_timer
- Using a thread (see: [Python threading.timer - repeat function every 'n' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)) and simply calling that thread with the timer after your spear-animation

The following has nothing to do with the error itself but your code is poorly designed in general so this might help:
You are trying to call a function from the game (in this case gameover) from an instance of the class (in this case enemy), which is a bad practice and semantically incorrect. The Enemy-Class shouldn't know the game at all, it should however be used by the game - not the other way around. It can fire certain events, but a different, global handler should take care of when the game is over (and similar game-related events), not a single instance of a class.

Also, instead of having endless if-else conditions you should consider using some kind of mapping - for example a dictionary. It'll safe you many lines of code, it's easier to maintain and also more readable.

Comment: Thanks i will try it out! I know my code isn't great but iv'e just started python and honestly don't know any better when it comes to making it correct etc...

Comment: That's why I mentioned it, otherwise you won't have a chance to improve! Once you feel more comfortable using Python or other programming languages I highly suggest you read about general good and bad practices and programming patterns! If you've come any further with that code or if you run into new issues just let me know.

Comment: Ok thanks i agree thats it important to clean up my code! However i dont see how storing the values in a dictionary would work. I would store the images and then have to put them into an if loop to make one image go to another?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, and it isn't an issue with delays or anything like that, it's an issue with your code.

Where it has the following code:

```
if self.currentImage == 4 or 5 or 6 or 7:
    #image of him attacking flipped
    self.currentImage = 9
    SpearAttack.play(loops = 0, maxtime = 10)
    #Tried putting gameover here but it skips the animation
```

Put gameover there. Here is the line of code that has the issue:

```
if self.currentImage == 4 or 5 or 6 or 7:
```

Python does not work that way.  Saying that will always return true.  You are thinking that is the same as:

```
if self.currentImage == 4 or self.currentImage == 5 or self.currentImage == 6 or self.currentImage == 7:
```

It is not.  You are saying this:

```
if (self.currentImage == 4) or (5) or (6) or (7):
```

Any integer other than 0 always returns true.

Try the following line of code, this should work:

```
if self.currentImage in [4,5,6,7]:
```

Have fun Pygaming! (If that's a word)

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my mistake! but unfortunately it dint solve the issue at hand as i need to implement some kind of timer to wait for the animation to finish.

Comment: Does anything else need to be going on while the animation is playing?

Comment: yes there is the animation of the enemy attack as above and the animation on my character dying.

Comment: Are those animations the ONLY things that are happening, or are calculations happening in the process?  If there are just animations, then I can just edit my answer to explain how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you define something you call it or the function, you should import `time`:

```
import time
```

Then after the animation do:

```
time.sleep(0.5)
GameOver()
```

Comment: `time.sleep` is not good idea because it stops everything - even animation.