# Running a background thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

All the examples I've been able to get to don't really address my problem, of having a certain procedure in the background constantly looping, while the rest of the program continues.

Here is a simple example of a method that works, using _thread:

```
import _thread
import time


def countSeconds():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Second")
    _thread.start_new(countSeconds, ())

def countTenSeconds():
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Ten seconds passed")
    _thread.start_new(countTenSeconds, ())


_thread.start_new(countSeconds, ())
_thread.start_new(countTenSeconds, ())
```

Ignoring the obvious fact that we could track the seconds, and just print something different if it's a multiple of ten, how would I go about creating this more efficiently.

In my actual program, the threading seems to be guzzling RAM, I assume from creating multiple instance of the thread. Do I have to "start_new" thread at the end of each procedure?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Re-calling a thread in itself doesn't seem really reasonable, maybe something like this is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module? It will be simpler than using the low-level [_thread](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/_thread.html) module. Also, thanks to the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), threaded Python applications are not actually parallel - you need [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for that.

Comment: i agree with @skrrgwasme.  I would be using threading (or asyncio). Furthermore, this is the whole objective of threading (run multiple threads [tasks] concurrently within a single process)...

Answer (score 6):

> All the examples I've been able to get to don't really address my problem
> Which examples?

This does work for me.

```
import threading
import time

def f():
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Function out!"

t1 = threading.Thread(target=f)

print "Starting thread"
t1.start()
time.sleep(0.1)
print "Something done"
t1.join()
print "Thread Done"
```

---

You're asking for a repeated thread, I don't get what exactly you need, this might work:

```
import threading
import time

var = False
def f():
    counter = 0
    while var:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print "Function {} run!".format(counter)
        counter+=1

t1 = threading.Thread(target=f)

print "Starting thread"
var = True
t1.start()
time.sleep(3)
print "Something done"
var = False
t1.join()
print "Thread Done"
```

Comment: The problem with this example is that it is not recursive. It is running the function once, and then quitting.

Answer (score 4):

use the `threading.timer` to continue launching a new background thread

```
import threading
import time


def countSeconds():
    print("Second")
    threading.Timer(1, countSeconds).start()

def countTenSeconds():
    print("Ten seconds passed")
    threading.Timer(10, countTenSeconds).start()


threading.Timer(1, countSeconds).start()
threading.Timer(10, countTenSeconds).start()
```