# How to kill the calling process when it spawned thread dies in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

My python script calls another python scripts method (which runs an infinite loop and performs some activity) and runs it as thread. I want to kill my calling python script as soon as the thread dies

Comment: Make the other python script add '1' to a txt when it's done, and then put a while loop in the original, and once it detects the '1', then end the program

Comment: my called python script runs an infinite loop. It cannot end. if it gets killed somehow then I want to terminate parent

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the module `threading`? If so, you could periodically check the status of your thread via the method [`threading.is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive).

If your infinite thread is killed somehow, your permanently checking main thread (possibly notified by another thread initialized like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)) can also terminate.