# Is there anyway to reuse thread when the requirements is met

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm making a mini-game in Python. The idea is that, when the object is near the player within a fixed distance, the thread is started and repeated after an amount of times.

For example:

```
class RepeatedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self._timer     = None
        self.interval   = interval
        self.function   = function
        self.args       = args
        self.kwargs     = kwargs
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()

    def _run(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self._timer = Timer(self.interval, self._run)
            self._timer.start()
            self.is_running = True

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()
        self.is_running = False
def ObjectHit(player):
    player.power = player.power + 5


if((Object_A_pos_x == player_pos_x + distance or Object_A_pos_x == player_pos_x - distance) and
   (Object_A_pos_y == player_pos_y + distance or Object_A_pos_y == player_pos_y - distance)):
    tA = RepeatedTimer(10, ObjectHit, player)
    % Thread t starts after every 10 seconds


else:
    t.stop()
```

I want that many object affect to the player separately in the same way. For example, object A is near the player for 23 seconds and then object B comes. So now there are two thread which are tA and tB. After that, object A leaves so the thread tA stops but the tB keeps running until the objectB leaves. And these apply similarly to objectC, objectD, ....

---

I have read some documentation about reusing and spawning thread such as `ThreadPool` and `concurrent.futures`. However, i'm new to multithreading so i don't have very clear idea about these.

---

Thanks alot for helping me.

Comment: You might find useful hints at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds

Please note that due to the Global Interpreter Lock some interpreters allow only one native thread to execute at a time

Comment: Read about [threading.html#barrier-objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#barrier-objects)