# Repeat a threaded timer with a start delay

Tags: python, subclass

I've been using the code from another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48741004/4603445) which works well but I would like to add some functionality.  The following class creates a threaded timer that starts immediately after the start method is called.  I would like the timer to wait some length of time before starting the repeating timer.

```
import time
from threading import Timer

class RepeatTimer(Timer):
    def run(self):
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

def hello():
    print('hello')

t = RepeatTimer(2, hello)
t.start()
```

This will print "hello" every two seconds until `t.cancel()` is called.

I would like for the timer to wait N number of seconds before starting the repeating timer.  I tried modifying the class to take an additional parameter, but it does not work.

```
class RepeatTimer(Timer):
    def __init__(self, initial_delay):
        super().__init__()
        self.initial_delay = initial_delay
    
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(initial_delay)
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

t = RepeatTimer(2, hello, 5)
```

With the error??

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I've also tried adding all of the Timer arguments to the `__init__` method but that doesn't help.

```
class RepeatTimer(Timer):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, initial_delay):
        super().__init__()
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.initial_delay = initial_delay
    
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(initial_delay)
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

t = RepeatTimer(2, hello, 5)
```

```py
 TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'interval' and 'function'
```

I think I'm struggling with creating a subclass of Timer. Suggestions welcomed?

Comment: your error is because in your RepeatTimer(2, hello, 5), that is more than the arguement requestion for  __init__(self, initial_delay): which is one.

Comment: You are getting close with your second example: change `super().__init__()` with `super().__init__(interval, function)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, [Jacques Gaudin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388292/jacques-gaudin). I had the super() syntax wrong.

```
class RepeatTimer(Timer):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, initial_delay):
        super().__init__(interval, function)
        self.initial_delay = initial_delay

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(initial_delay)
        while not self.finished.wait(self.interval):
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```