# Improper answer while using Timer module in Google Colabs

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am typing this code in Google Colabs

```
def mytimer(): 
     print("Python Program\n") 
my_timer = threading.Timer(0.8, mytimer) 
my_timer.start() 
print("Bye\n")
```

In some cases I get the output as

```
Bye
```

At other times, I get

```
Bye

Python Program
```

Why is this difference occuring? Should I add any other line of code? Or any criteria I should be careful about?

Answer (score 0):

[image: with 0.1]You are missing few things here [image]

```
import logging
import threading
import time
def mytimer(): 
     print("Python Program\n") 
my_timer = threading.Timer(0.2, mytimer) # change it to 0.8 will not print
my_timer.start() 
print("Bye\n")
```

threading.Timer - As per docs Call a function after a specified number of seconds when it is 0.2 it will call that function and it prints both when it is 0.8 it is not calling that function so it is not calling, This has nothing to do with colab 
you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)

Comment: i didn't get the effect of timing  difference

Comment: i didn't get why it is getting printed when the time is 0.2 and not getting printed when it is 0.8?could any one explain

Comment: threading.Timer(interval, function, args = None, kwargs = None)  , It calls the function after 0.2 Seconds is passed in your case it calls                                def mytimer(): 
     print("Python Program\n"). However when it is 0.8 seconds that much time is not passed so it doesn't call that function just prints the next statement print("Bye\n") . Hope this helps for better understanding use the link in earlier answer and read python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html