# How can I put a sleep timer in a function and execute it in python to call driver. close() for a selenium script

Tags: python, function, selenium, sleep

I have a bit of a complicated selenium script but it contains an error response (I dont want to) handle because it will ruin another selenium command in the script, long story short I want to define

```
driver. close()
```

at the beginning of the script and call it in 2 minutes REGARDLESS.

```
def mytimer():
    time.sleep(120)
    driver.close()
mytimer()    

// Lots of selenium and webdriver stuff that will finish in 2 minutes because above as called a function that sleeps for 2 minutes and then calls driver.close()
```

Comment: Mind rephrasing the order of things you'd like to happen? Are you wanting to close out first then wait 2 minutes? Are you hinting you want to rest for 2 minutes to avoid potential throttling and you'd like your script to detect if throttling has been detected (in error response) then chill for 2 minutes before re-trying?

Comment: @dnunez32 I want to run some selenium stuff in a python script, and I want "driver.close()" to be called at 2 minutes from the script starting, regardless if selenium hangs due to an error response

Comment: You could be thinking of a timer thread that runs along side your selenium script 2 minutes of you kicking off/running it. Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds The post by Andrew Wilkins may help you out. After sleeping for 120 you'll do your driver.close().

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by executing the timer function in another thread. Example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import threading
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("url")

def mytimer():
    sleep(120)
    driver.close()

x = threading.Thread(target=mytimer)
x.start()

# rest of you code ...
```