# Is there any way I can run a program at the exact start of a minute?

Tags: python

I want to run the program at the exact start of a minute (eg. 1:30:00, 1:20:00, 1:19:00 [Hour,minute,seconds]) There are many similar questions but they do not have the case in which the program is linked to a defined time, not just 60 second intervals. Other solutions are in other languages. Is there any python solution to this problem?

Comment: Check Celery - https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

Comment: You mean for you program to be executed at a specific time? Like from a scheduler?
Or a process in your program to start at a specific time?

Comment: For the part of the program to be run at a specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I guess the best you can do is to combine the answer here:
[Python threading.timer - repeat function every 'n' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)

but change the wait condition based on current time:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

when you create your thread compute how much time it has to wait before it gets executed.
Then it should within miliseconds precision start at the designated time.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are several options available. Here are three that I know of:

1. You can build your own solution using the `sched` package in the Python standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html
2. There is a third-party package called `schedule`, with the periodic functionality that you requested: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
3. As suggested in the comments, the Celery task queue library has a component called "Celery beat", which you can use to schedule periodic tasks: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#guide-beat

Note that the first two libraries are not inherently multi-threaded. I'm not sure exactly what happens if a job blocks the main thread and overlaps the next scheduled run. You will need to consult the documentation for that, or ensure that all your jobs run in a non-blocking fashion.