# Python: Periodically run http requests in thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
import json
import threading

data = {
  "amount": 2
}


def foo(data):
    try:
        r = requests.post(url = "www.mysite.com", data = data)
        j = json.loads(r.text)
        print(j)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise SystemExist(e)


threading.Timer(1, foo, [data]).start()
```

I want to run this http request every second using a thread in my program. However, the program only runs the http request once and exit. How do I fix this?

Comment: `Timer` objects only run once after a given number of seconds. See [Python threading.timer - repeat function every 'n' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)

Comment: or you can create infinite `while`-loop inside thread instead of using `Timer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart the timer after each request :

```
def foo(data):
    try:
        r = requests.post(url = "www.mysite.com", data = data)
        j = json.loads(r.text)
        print(j)
        threading.Timer(1, foo, [data]).start() # New Line Added
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise SystemExist(e)
```

Comment: Thank you. The approach looks differently from the link suggested by some people https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds . Could you elaborate the pros and cons?

Comment: Personally I don't like wait loops unless i need to use them, but the best thing to do if you are concerned is to measure any differences.

Comment: What kind of differences?

Comment: There might be performance differences depending on your system loading, and other loading conditions in your applications - it might affect overall throughput etc, CPU usage etc.