# Creating an alarm in seconds Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, unix, time, timer

I am trying to code a function that recognizes when X amount of seconds has passed without pausing the program, so without using `time.sleep`. How would I be able to do that by using the `unix timestamp`? So for the code below it would print `5 seconds has passed` for every 5 seconds that passes.

```
import time
X = 5
TIME = time.time()
```

Comment: You should use threads in order to continue the program without stopping the main thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python threading.timer - repeat function every 'n' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Check this will help you avoid using time.sleep() and your code will be iterating till the time reaches next X seconds

```
import time
startTime = time.time()
X = 5
timeDif = 0
while timeDif < X:
    currentTime = time.time()
    timeDif = currentTime - startTime
```