# Python does something every 5 minutes

Tags: python, time

i need to check data on an API. The API is refreshed with new data every 5 minutes (10:00, 10:05, 10:10 etc...)

I don't want to use time.sleep(300) because i want my script to do something at 10:05:03, then 10:05:03 etc. and not 5 min avec the script started (maybe it started at 10h12
How can i build this?

Thanks y'all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python threading.timer - repeat function every 'n' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)

Comment: Thanks for the help but i do not want to use something based on 300sec. Because i want it to perfectly start on HH:05 then HH:10 then HH:15 etc... not HH:18 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Just wanted to remove the possibility of recursion error, so I have rewritten the code:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import datetime

def check_api():
    # ... your code here ...
    pass

def schedule_api():
    while datetime.datetime.now().minute % 5 != 0:
        sleep(1)
    check_api()
    while True:
        sleep(300)
        check_api()

thread = Thread(target=schedule_api)
thread.start()
```

Also if you want your thread to quit when the main program exits you could set daemon as True on the thread like:

```py
thread.daemon = True
```

But this does not enforce a clean termination of this thread so you could also try this approach below:

```py
# ...
RUNNING = True
# ...
thread = Thread(target=schedule_api)
thread.start()
#...
def main():
    # ... all main code ...
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        RUNNING = False
```

---

You can use the following code:

```py
import threading

def check_api():
    pass

timer_thread = threading.Timer(300, check_api)
timer_thread.start()
# call timer_thread.cancel() when you need it to stop
```

This will call your `check_api` function every 5 minutes and will not block your main code's execution.

as mentioned by @scotyy3785 the above code will only run once but I realize what you want and have written the code for it:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import datetime


def check_api():
    # ... your code here ...
    pass


def caller(callback_func, first=True):
    if first:
        while not datetime.datetime.now().minute % 5 == 0:
            sleep(1)
    callback_func()
    sleep(300)
    caller(callback_func, False)


thread = Thread(target=caller, args=(check_api,))
thread.start()

# you'll have to handle the still running thread on exit
```

The above code will call `check_api` at minutes like 00, 05, 10, 15...

Comment: Worth noting that threading.Timer will only execute once so this example will execute check_api after 5 minute and not again at 10, 15, 20 etc. To do this, the timer would need to rescheduled.

Comment: Sure, how can i rescheduled it ?

Comment: I have updated my answer according to what you need...

Comment: I mistakenly added a block of while loop, removed it. check if it works for you now?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the help, i'm testing it right now. Come back if i get troubles, thanks !

Comment: I just realised this might give you a maximum recursion depth exceeded error after a long time, don't have my machine right now, check back tomorrow for fix

Answer (score 0):

Check the time regularly in a loop and do something at certain minute marks:

```
import time

# returns the next 5 minute mark
# e.g. at minute 2 return 5
def get_next_time():
    minute = time.localtime().tm_min
    result = 5 - (minute % 5) + minute
    if result == 60:
        result = 0
    return result

next_run = get_next_time()

while True:
    now = time.localtime()
    # at minute 0, 5, 10... + 3 seconds:
    if next_run == now.tm_min and now.tm_sec >= 3:
        print("checking api")
        next_run = get_next_time()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Seems to answer more precisly. I'm gonna test this, thanks :)