# Optimizing Real-time Video Frame Capture Python/cv2

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, video-capture

I have a thread dedicated to reading frames from a camera, aiming to read at a specific frequency (`self.target_fps`). Therefore, I need to perform a read every `self.target_frequency = 1 / self.target_fps`.

The video thread runs a loop where it reads at each iteration, regardless of the target frequency (target_fps), to empty the VideoCapture buffer (particularly useful when self.target_fps is low, for example, 1 fps). After the read, I want to add the frame to a queue only if it's the right time, i.e., if a time interval equal to self.target_frequency has passed. The "`start`" timer helps me determine **when it's time to enqueue the frame and when it's not**. Are there better approaches for **efficiently** reading frames from an RTSP camera and achieving a reasonably **accurate** frame rate?

```py
            self.target_fps = 7
            self.target_frequency = 1 / self.target_fps

            start = time.time()

            while not self.stop_video_thread.is_set():
                success, frame = cap.read()

                interval = time.time() - start

                if interval >= self.target_frequency:
                    start = time.time()

                    if success:
                        frame_queue.put_nowait(frame)
```

Comment: you don't control when the camera takes a picture by throttling it. it produces frames at its own pace, set by the FPS parameter.

Comment: try setting the FPS attribute of the RTSP VideoCapture object. maybe it works. maybe it doesn't. that'd be the most efficient solution.

Comment: if that doesn't work and you have to receive all frames, then you need to discard selected frames yourself. the logic for that will involve timestamps, so you know which frames to keep.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the `set` method of `VideoCapture` to adjust the frame rate of the camera. For example, `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, self.target_fps)` will set the frame rate to your desired value. This way, you don't need to check the interval every time you read a frame.
- You can use a `threading.Timer` object to schedule the reading of frames at regular intervals. For example, `timer = threading.Timer(self.target_frequency, read_frame)` will create a timer that calls the `read_frame` function every `self.target_frequency` seconds. better than a while loop
- You can use a `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of a `queue.Queue` to share the frames between processes. So you can avoid the overhead of [pickling and unpickling the frames](https://answers.opencv.org/question/215278/how-to-optimize-frame-grabbing-from-video-stream-in-opencv/).

```py
import cv2
import threading
import multiprocessing as mp

def read_frame(cap, frame_queue):
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if success:
        frame_queue.put(frame)
    timer = threading.Timer(self.target_frequency, read_frame, args=(cap, frame_queue))
    timer.start()

def main():
    # Create a video capture object and set the frame rate
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp_address')
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, self.target_fps)

    frame_queue = mp.Queue()

    timer = threading.Timer(self.target_frequency, read_frame, args=(cap, frame_queue))
    timer.start()

    while True:
        frame = frame_queue.get()
        # Process the frame here
        #########################
```

Comment: If you have set CAP_PROP_FPS, why are you also using a timed timer with self.target_frequency?

Comment: @giulius 
The timer ensures consistent frame reading. The `CAP_PROP_FPS` property may not work well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It seems to be working well. Now I'm wondering, is there a better way to create a repetitive timer thread? From the code you wrote, it looks like a recursive function where with each call, a new timer is created.

Comment: @giulius 
 It is not a recursive function, because it does not call itself directly, but rather passes itself as an argument to the `threading.Timer` object. This way, the function is executed only once by each timer thread, and a new timer thread is created only after the previous one finishes.
Another possible way to create a repetitive timer thread is to use a subclass of the `threading.Timer` class, as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds)
However, this approach may not be as flexible.

Comment: multiprocessing is overkill. it requires pickling. threading and queue.Queue is good enough. -- there is no point to scheduling a timer. just run a thread that blocks on the `vid.read()` call. that is reasonable to do. to decimate the frames you've captured down to the desired frame rate, just discard whichever frames you don't need. the rest is logic involving timestamps. -- if you're lucky, you can somehow configure the source stream's frame rate... if that's an ability of RTSP, then you can hope that OpenCV will let you set it. otherwise, you'll have to do it separately.