# Improve current implementation of a setInterval

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to figure out how to make a setInterval that cancels in python without making an entire new class to do that, I figured out how but now I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

The code below seems to work fine, but I have not *thoroughly* tested it.

```
import threading
def setInterval(func, sec):
    def inner():
        while function.isAlive():
            func()
            time.sleep(sec)
    function = type("setInterval", (), {}) # not really a function I guess
    function.isAlive = lambda: function.vars["isAlive"]
    function.vars = {"isAlive": True}
    function.cancel = lambda: function.vars.update({"isAlive": False})
    thread = threading.Timer(sec, inner)
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()
    return function
interval = setInterval(lambda: print("Hello, World"), 60) # will print Hello, World every 60 seconds
# 3 minutes later
interval.cancel() # it will stop printing Hello, World
```

Is there a way to do the above without making a dedicated class that inherits from `threading.Thread` or using the `type("setInterval", (), {})` ? Or am I stuck in deciding  between making a dedicated class or continue to use `type`

Comment: Using `type` is equivalent to explicitly declaring an inner class inside `setInterval`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To call a function repeatedly with `interval` seconds between the calls and the ability to cancel future calls:

```
from threading import Event, Thread

def call_repeatedly(interval, func, *args):
    stopped = Event()
    def loop():
        while not stopped.wait(interval): # the first call is in `interval` secs
            func(*args)
    Thread(target=loop).start()    
    return stopped.set
```

Example:

```
cancel_future_calls = call_repeatedly(60, print, "Hello, World")
# ...
cancel_future_calls()
```

Note: this version waits around `interval` seconds after each call no matter how long `func(*args)` takes. If metronome-like ticks are desired then the execution could be locked with a `timer()`: `stopped.wait(interval)` could be replaced with `stopped.wait(interval - timer() % interval)` where `timer()` defines the current time (it may be relative) in seconds e.g., `time.time()`. See [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251804/4279)

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely an improvement, looks cleaner too.

Comment: Be careful about running this in the background, when your main thread throws an unhandled exception - wrap `# ...` in `try: (...) finally: cancel_future_calls()`. (This includes the common `KeyboardInterrupt`).

Comment: @TomaszGandor: you could pass `daemon=True` so that the background thread dies if the program exits unexpectedly. Or make it into a context manager: `with calling_repeatedly(interval, func, *args): <code block>` if you want to repeat the function while the code block is executed e.g., to collect some performance statistics: memory, cpu percentage, etc. There could be other cases. Returning the handle which may cancel future calls is the most flexible approach.

Comment: How do I stop the interval from inside the function

Comment: @CoderGautamYT: just like with any other Python function, you could use `return` to exit the function.