# Run two commands at once in python script

Tags: python

I am trying to get two things to work at once when the C command is used.

```
    if command == 'C':
            os.system('aplay /home/pi/sound/cclaw.wav')
            motor = mh.getMotor(3)
            motor.setSpeed(150)
            motor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.BACKWARD)
            time.sleep(2.5)
```

The sound plays then the motor runs. I need the sound to play at the same time as the motor runs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)

Comment: did you try running the command in the background, with `&`?

Comment: ive looked at that thread, i do not understand it and it is old. so i know i wont get any response if i ask a question on there

Comment: no could you please explain, i am learning and am clueless when it comes to this

Comment: Please use this as a reference [Python - run two commands at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733934/python-run-two-commands-at-the-same-time),
Also , I would suggest you use pyMedia for opening your audio file rather than using `os` since the latter is terribly expensive.

Comment: That wouldn't be the right place to ask a question anyway, [so] is for Q+A, not a forum, you should explain on this question why that duplicate didn't help... But having saying that, does running the motor straight after the sound not suffice? I wouldn't imagine much latency there