# Creating a timer in python

Tags: python, time

```
import time
def timer():
   now = time.localtime(time.time())
   return now[5]


run = raw_input("Start? > ")
while run == "start":
   minutes = 0
   current_sec = timer()
   #print current_sec
   if current_sec == 59:
      mins = minutes + 1
      print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", mins
```

I want to create a kind of stopwatch that when minutes reach 20 minutes, brings up a dialog box, The dialog box is not the problem. But my minutes variable does not increment in this code.

Comment: Hey Guys, I don't think my question is been answered The concept is to write a code that pops up a dialog box after some specified that time

Comment: Your code attempts to print a timer tick every minute. Do you want the final code to do that, or just pop up a dialog box?

Comment: Just a pop up at the end of probably 15 minutes that i'll set

Comment: here's [how to call a function with a delay using different libraries: Tkinter, Twisted, Asyncio, Gtk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can really simplify this whole program by using [`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
import time
run = raw_input("Start? > ")
mins = 0
# Only run if the user types in "start"
if run == "start":
    # Loop until we reach 20 minutes running
    while mins != 20:
        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> {}".format(mins))
        # Sleep for a minute
        time.sleep(60)
        # Increment the minute total
        mins += 1
    # Bring up the dialog box here
```

Comment: What does time.sleep do?

Comment: @user2711485 - It suspends the computer for however many seconds you tell it (in this case 60, which is a minute).  In other words, it is saying "do nothing until this time runs out".

Comment: Is it possible to have other code running while using time.sleep() eg if you were making a game could the timer run in the background or would everything stop when time.sleep() is called?

Comment: @Qwertieϟ - Everything would be suspended until the call to `time.sleep` finished.  That is the purpose of `time.sleep`: to stop program execution for a certain period of time.

Comment: @Qwertieϟ - Use [Timer objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) for that. Or the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) library in general.

Comment: What is raw_input. I get->  NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Answer (score 69):

See [Timer Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) from threading.

How about

```
from threading import Timer

def timeout():
    print("Game over")

# duration is in seconds
t = Timer(20 * 60, timeout)
t.start()

# wait for time completion
t.join()
```

Should you want pass arguments to the `timeout` function, you can give them in the timer constructor:

```
def timeout(foo, bar=None):
    print('The arguments were: foo: {}, bar: {}'.format(foo, bar))

t = Timer(20 * 60, timeout, args=['something'], kwargs={'bar': 'else'})
```

Or you can use `functools.partial` to create a bound function, or you can pass in an instance-bound method.

Comment: why do i need the "time.sleep(1500)"

Comment: it is an example so that your main does not drop out right away :D

Comment: In gui application you would just continue your mainloop.

Comment: OKay, so your code means when t is started it executes anything in the  timeout function  in that time interval?

Comment: the timeout function is executed once after 20 minutes.

Comment: What if we need to pass an argument in timeout() ?

Comment: I want to use this to program an LCD screen timeout (after x seconds the light is off).
How can I check if the timer is already running to reset it? (if the user pressa a button and extends LCD timeout, in other words)

Comment: This is _much_ more elegant than the accepted answer since it doesn't block the hole process.

Answer (score 7):

I'd use a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

...
period = timedelta(minutes=1)
next_time = datetime.now() + period
minutes = 0
while run == 'start':
    if next_time <= datetime.now():
        minutes += 1
        next_time += period
```

Comment: While this works, constantly running while loops can consume a lot of processing power. Adding a sleep period (even only a second) can greatly reduce that usage.

Comment: Definitely. [Busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) loops are "considered an anti-pattern and should be avoided, as processor time that could be used to execute a different task is instead wasted on useless activity."

Answer (score 2):

Your code's perfect except that you must do the following replacement:

```
minutes += 1 #instead of mins = minutes + 1
```

or

```
minutes = minutes + 1 #instead of mins = minutes + 1
```

but here's another solution to this problem:

```
def wait(time_in_seconds):
    time.sleep(time_in_seconds) #here it would be 1200 seconds (20 mins)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mins = minutes + 1
```

should be

```
minutes = minutes + 1
```

Also,

```
minutes = 0
```

needs to be outside of the while loop.

Comment: Also, `minutes = 0` needs to be outside of the `while` loop if you are going to stick with this code.  But really, he should probably just use something better suited to the task.

Comment: How about `minutes += 1`?

Answer (score 1):

*I want to create a kind of stopwatch that when minutes reach 20 minutes, brings up a dialog box*.

All you need is to sleep the specified time. time.sleep() takes seconds to sleep, so 20 * 60 is 20 minutes.

```
import time
run = raw_input("Start? > ")
time.sleep(20 * 60)
your_code_to_bring_up_dialog_box()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# this is kind of timer, stop after the input minute run out.    
import time
min=int(input('>>')) 
while min>0:
    print min
    time.sleep(60) # every minute 
    min-=1  # take one minute
```

Comment: hope my poor language would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
import time 

...

def stopwatch(mins):
   # complete this whole code in some mins.
   time.sleep(60*mins)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
mintt=input("How many seconds you want to time?:")
timer=int(mintt)
while (timer != 0 ):
    timer=timer-1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(timer)
```

This work very good to time seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for a Timer object: http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: Using a timer object could get tricky if the action it triggers is non-trivial.  You have to deal with thread synchronization issues if you use a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Try having your while loop like this:

```
minutes = 0

while run == "start":
   current_sec = timer()
   #print current_sec
   if current_sec == 59:
      minutes = minutes + 1
      print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", mins
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
def timer(n):
    while n!=0:
        n=n-1
        time.sleep(n)#time.sleep(seconds) #here you can mention seconds according to your requirement.
        print "00 : ",n
timer(30) #here you can change n according to your requirement.
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> import time
> def timer():
>    now = time.localtime(time.time())
>    return now[5]
>
>
> run = raw_input("Start? > ")
> while run == "start":
>    minutes = 0
>    current_sec = timer()
>    #print current_sec
>    if current_sec == 59:
>       mins = minutes + 1
>       print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>", mins
> ```

I was actually looking for a timer myself and your code seems to work, the probable reason for your minutes not being counted is that when you say that

> minutes = 0

and then

> mins = minutes + 1

it is the same as saying

> mins = 0 + 1

I'm betting that every time you print mins it shows you "1" because of what i just explained, "0+1" will always result in "1".

What you have to do first is place your

> minutes = 0

declaration outside of your while loop. After that you can delete the

> mins = minutes + 1

line because you don't really need another variable in this case, just replace it with

> minutes = minutes + 1

That way minutes will start off with a value of "0", receive the new value of "0+1", receive the new value of "1+1", receive the new value of "2+1", etc.

I realize that a lot of people answered it already but i thought it would help out more, learning wise, if you could see where you made a mistake and try to fix it.Hope it helped. Also, thanks for the timer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
now=datetime.now()
Sec=-1
sec=now.strftime("%S")
SEC=0
while True:
    SEC=int(SEC)
    sec=int(sec)
    now=datetime.now()
    sec=now.strftime("%S")
    if SEC<sec:
        Sec+=1
    SEC=sec
print(Sec) #the timer is Sec
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).