# How can i create timer or contdown in python?

Tags: python, timer, python-module

Is there any function or way that I can greate timer in python?

For example:you have 5 seconds to slove this question or maybe to calculate total time for solving this question
The simple one countdown:
[image]

Comment: Have you googled create timer in python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406165/creating-a-timer-in-python

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a timer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406165/creating-a-timer-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
import time
run = int(input(""))
if run:
    for i in range(1, run+1):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
```