# Real-time interrupts in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, time, interrupt

I have a Python 2.7 program running an infinite while loop and I want to incorporate a timer interrupt.
What I aim to do is to set off a timer at some point in the loop, and when 5 seconds have elapsed I want the code to branch to a specific part of the while loop.

What I have been doing so far is the following:
in each iteration of the while loop I am checking how much time has elapsed when I reach that point in the code using

```
time.clock()
```

and if the difference exceeds 5 I run the chunk of code I mean to run

However that way 7 seconds might pass before I evaluate the time, it will be >5sec but I want to go there **exactly** when 5 seconds pass

Also, I need this to work for more than 1 counter (possibly up to a 100) but I do not want the interrupts to interrupt each other. Using Timer did not work either.

I know this can be done using timer interrupts in assembly but how can I do that in python?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a single event is to be handled, then the easiest way is to use the `signal` framework which is a [standard module of Python](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html).

However, if we need a fully-fledged scheduler, then we have to resort to another module: `sched`.  [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) is a pointer to the official documentation.  Please be aware, though, that in multi-threaded environments `sched` **has limitations with respect to thread-safety**.

Another option is the [Advanced Python Scheduler](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/), which is not part of the standard distribution.

Comment: From my very limited experience with python what I understood is that signal or timer can be used for 1 event, how could I make a dynamic array of such events? this is turning out to be troublesome

Comment: So I am sending frames, and I want a timer for each frame, if a frame does not get acknowledged before *ITS OWN* timer sets off then when the timer does set off I want to resend that frame, and if timer2 sets off while I am sending a frame it has to wait, no interrupting except in specified places in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can't get [real-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) without special hardware/software support. You don't need it in most cases ([do you need to control giant robots?](http://pyvideo.org/video/481)).

How to delay several function calls by known numbers of seconds depends on your needs e.g., if a time it takes to run a function is negligible compared to the delay between the calls then you could [run all functions in a single thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
from Tkinter import Tk

root = Tk()
root.withdraw() # don't show the GUI window
root.after(1000, print, 'foo') # print foo in a second
root.after(0, print, 'bar') # print bar in a jiffy
root.after(2000, root.destroy) # exit mainloop in 2 seconds
root.mainloop()
print("done")
```

It implements yours *"I do not want the interrupts to interrupt each other either"* because the next callback is not called until the previous one is complete.