# Looking for a way to check for unexpected windows during a for loop in python automated testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, automated-tests, testcomplete

I am running some automated tests on an POS application where a large number of sales are entered using a for loop. During the test there are times where it is possible for the application window to lose focus, and when this happened we get a pop up window and this causes the test to stop.

I currently have a lot of checks in the code to look for this window after multiple steps in the loop, but each one I add adds time to the sale and slows the test down. Is there a way in python to constantly check for something like these windows.

To note I am using TestComplete and I have looked into the event handlers and it does not appear I will be able to use them due to how the application was developed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try to use an interrupt schedule. The basic idea is that you trigger a function (in this case your function checking for unexpected windows) whenever some counter reaches a value.

If you don't need to check at very specific and short time intervals it is enough to use something like `time.clock()`. I you DO need the abovementioned there are libraries for that, specifically the `signal` module or the more advanced `sched`, which are both part of the standard library (as far as I know, [Documentation of signal](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html), [Documentation of sched](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html)).

There are also other (external, non-standard) modules that can work, but `sched` and/or `signal` should be enough here.

Feel free to ask if any further question should arise.

This SO post might also help: [real time interrupts in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170318/real-time-interrupts-in-python)