# Python time delay

Tags: python, time, delay, turtle-graphics

Alright, I want to know how to delay a portion of a program without pausing the entire program.
I'm not necessarily good at python so if you could give me a relatively simple answer if possible, that would be great.

I want to have a turtle draw a circle on screen every time this function is called, this is what I have:

```
import time
from random import randint
turtle5 = turtle.Turtle()    

coinx = randint(-200, 200)
coiny = randint(-200, 200)

turtle5.pu()
turtle5.goto(coinx, coiny)
turtle5.pd()
turtle5.begin_fill()
turtle5.fillcolor("Gold")
turtle5.circle(5, 360, 8)
turtle5.end_fill()
time.sleep(1)
turtle5.clear()
```

Comment: Which function? There is no function in the code you posted.

Comment: `Alright`, you have to be more specific.

Comment: You say you want to "delay a portion of a program without pausing the entire program."  OK, so what will your program do during the delay time, when it's *not* drawing the turtle?

Answer (score 2):

There is [`turtle.ontimer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.ontimer) that calls a function with the specified delay:

```
turtle.ontimer(your_function, delay_in_milliseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the part of the program you want to delay in its own thread, and then call sleep() in that thread.

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do in your example, so here is a simple example:

```
import time
import threading

def print_time(msg):
    print 'The time %s is: %s.' % (msg, time.ctime(time.time()))

class Wait(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, seconds):
        super(Wait, self).__init__()
        self.seconds = seconds
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.seconds)
        print_time('after waiting %d seconds' % self.seconds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wait_thread = Wait(5)
    wait_thread.start()
    print_time('now')
```

Output:

```
The time now is: Mon Jan 12 01:57:59 2015.
The time after waiting 5 seconds is: Mon Jan 12 01:58:04 2015.
```

Notice that we started the thread that will wait 5 seconds first, but it did not block the print_time('now') call, rather it waited in the background.

**EDIT:**

From J.F. Sebastian's comment, the simpler solution with threading is:

```
import time
import threading

def print_time(msg):
    print 'The time %s is: %s.' % (msg, time.ctime(time.time()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = threading.Timer(5, print_time, args = ['after 5 seconds'])
    t.start()
    print_time('now')
```

Comment: You don't need a custom thread subclass here. There is `threading.Timer`. You could avoid creating threads in a GUI (like `turtle`), networking code. See [Postponing functions in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279)