# Use of asyncio event loop recursively

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am new to asyncio ( used with python3.4 ) and I am not sure I use it as one should. I have seen in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177439/postponing-functions-in-python/14040516#14040516) that it can be use to execute a function every n seconds (in my case ms) without having to dive into threading.

I use it to get data from laser sensors through a basic serial protocol every n ms until I get m samples.

Here is the definition of my functions :

```
def countDown( self, 
               loop, 
               funcToDo, 
               *args, 
               counter = [ 1 ],
               **kwargs ):
    """ At every call, it executes funcToDo ( pass it args and kwargs )
        and count down from counter to 0. Then, it stop loop """
    if counter[ 0 ] == 0:
        loop.stop() 
    else:
        funcToDo( *args, **kwargs )
        counter[ 0 ] -= 1


def _frangeGen( self, start = 0, stop = None, step = 1 ):
    """ use to generate a time frange from start to stop by step step """
    while stop is None or start < stop:
        yield start
        start += step

def callEvery( self, 
               loop, 
               interval, 
               funcToCall, 
               *args, 
               now = True, 
               **kwargs ):
    """ repeat funcToCall every interval sec in loop object """
    nb = kwargs.get( 'counter', [ 1000 ] )
    def repeat( now = True,
                times = self._frangeGen( start = loop.time(),
                                         stop=loop.time()+nb[0]*interval,
                                         step = interval ) ):
        if now:
            funcToCall( *args, **kwargs )
        loop.call_at( next( times ), repeat )

    repeat( now = now )
```

And this is how I use it (getAllData is the function that manage serial communication) :

```
ts = 0.01
nbOfSamples = 1000
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
callEvery( loop, ts, countDown, loop, getAllData, counter = [nbOfSamples] )  
loop.run_forever()
```

I want to put that bloc into a function and call it as often as I want, something like this :

```
for i in range( nbOfMeasures ):
    myFunction()
    processData()
```

But the second test does not call getAllData 1000 times, only twice, sometimes thrice. The interesting fact is one time in two I get as much data as I want. I don't really understand, and I can't find anything in the docs, so I am asking for your help. Any explanation or an easier way to do it is gladly welcome :)

Comment: I haven't studied your code in depth, however, would it be possibly in your case to simply call funcToCall by running it inside a asyncio.async() task? You can use an asyncio.sleep() function inside a while True loop inside your funcToCall in order to let it 'sleep' for a set duration. Simply create as many of these tasks as you need and they will effectively run concurrently on the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things too much and, generally speaking, doing recursion when you have an event loop is bad design.
`asyncio` is *fun* only when you make use of coroutines. Here's one way of doing it:

```
import asyncio as aio

def get_laser_data():
  """
  get data from the laser using blocking IO
  """
  ...


@aio.coroutine  
def get_samples(loop, m, n):
  """
  loop = asyncio event loop
  m = number of samples
  n = time between samples
  """
  samples = []
  while len(samples) < m:
    sample = yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, get_laser_data)
    samples.append(sample)
    yield from aio.sleep(n)

  return samples

@aio.coroutine
def main(loop):
  for i in range(nbOfMeasures):
    samples = yield from get_samples(loop, 1000, 0.01)
    ...

loop = aio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
loop.close()
```

If you are completely confused by this, consider reading some tutorials/documentation about `asyncio`.

But I would like to point out that you **must** use a thread to get the data from the laser sensor. Doing any blocking IO in the same thread that the event loop is running will block the loop and throw off `aio.sleep`. This is what `yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, get_laser_data)` is doing. It's running the `get_laser_data` function in a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am slowly understanding how things work, but coroutines still resist me. Anyway, your solution does not fit my need since it sleep **after** the execution of the `get_laser_data` function, thus it will be called every n sec + the time to execute `get_laser_data`.

Comment: You could call `loop.time()` before and after a call to `get_laser_data`, and then remove the difference when sleeping: `aio.sleep(n-(after-before))`. But, you will always have some error because of the resolution of the `asycnio` clock. Internally, it's using the `monotonic` clock from the `time` module. If you need more precise timing, I would recommend using the `perf_counter` from `time` & instead of using `asyncio` write a simple loop to do the sleeping.

Comment: I have try a simple while loop with a sleep function (that was my first try actually). I am not precise enough, even with `time.perf_counter()`, but I think it is due to the precision of the `time.sleep()` function. I have come to an ugly solution using loop, so for now I am trying the threading.Timer class to find a cleaner way.

Comment: On my system `perf_counter` has a resolution of `1e-09`. If you need to be more precise than that, then Python is not the way to go. Plus, I don't see how using a Thread will be any better. If anything, you will loose precision. Internally, Python only runs one thread at a time, switching them every x instructions. To get really precise you need as little abstraction as possible between you & the hardware clocks.

Comment: `perf_counter` is precise enough, but not `time.sleep`. My function execution time is between 7 and 14 ms. If I want to do it every 20ms, than I need to time.sleep 6ms in the worst case. When I try to do it 100 times, my code is run in a averaging 2,04 seconds.
And you are right, using a thread is not better, just _cleaner_. (I did not manage to make it work actually)

Comment: Have you tried a busy sleep? Basically, a while loop inside the while loop, looping until some time is reached. Also try messing with the `sys.setswitchinterval` setting.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.5, you can make use of the [`async for`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#async-for) syntax and create an [asynchronous iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-iterator) to control your time frames. It has to implement the [`__aiter__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__aiter__) and [`__anext__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__anext__) methods:

```
class timeframes(collections.AsyncIterator):

    def __init__(self, steps, delay=1.0, *, loop=None):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() if loop is None else loop
        self.ref = self.loop.time()
        self.delay = delay
        self.steps = steps
        self.iter = iter(range(steps))

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            when = self.ref + next(self.iter) * self.delay
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        else:
            future = asyncio.Future()
            self.loop.call_at(when, future.set_result, None)
            await future
            return self.loop.time()

    async def __aiter__(self):
        return self
```

Here's a coroutine that simulates an execution:

```
async def simulate(steps, delay, execution):
    # Prepare timing
    start = loop.time()
    expected = steps * delay - delay + execution
    # Run simulation
    async for t in timeframes(steps, delay):
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, time.sleep, execution)
    # Return error
    result = loop.time() - start
    return result - expected
```

And this is the kind of result you'll get on a linux OS:

```
>>> loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
>>> simulation = simulate(steps=1000, delay=0.020, execution=0.014)
>>> error = loop.run_until_complete(simulation)
>>> print("Overall error = {:.3f} ms".format(error * 1000))
Overall error = 1.199 ms
```

It is different on a windows OS (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133888/2846140)) but the event loop will catch up and the overall error should never exceed 15 ms.