# Python Daemon, repeat function every x seconds

Tags: python, daemon

I want to repeat a function every x seconds when the code its working like deamon in Python 2.6 for Linux.
I have some code but its giving me a lot of problems. Is it possible to call a another file.py instead to write the code inside?

Here is the code:

```
import daemon   
import threading

def hello():
    print "hello, world"
    t = threading.Timer(2.0, hello).start()

def run():
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        hello()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Your question might have been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223157/how-to-execute-a-function-asynchronously-every-60-seconds-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
import daemon   
import threading
import another_file

def problematic_func_loop():
    another_file.peoblematic_func()
    t = threading.Timer(60.0, problematic_func_loop).start()

def run():
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
        problematic_func_loop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: i've tried the code above but i got `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DaemonContext'`

Comment: i figured it out, it was a versioning issue, the daemon package in pypi was 1.5.5 which has DaemonContext, the version installed with pip command was 1.0, which hasn't.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it isn't worth working through the daemon-specific details.  Have a look at [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), a process control system that makes it easy to wrap daemonic behaviors around existing applications.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Fat Controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/) which can repeat any program every x seconds.   It can also handle failures and offer strategies for parallel execution if needed and also the ability to run as a daemon.

There's documentation, examples and use cases at the official website:

http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/