# Making a timer in python whilst recording an input

Tags: python, input, timer, countdown

I'm trying to create a program that runs in a similar format to the game show Countdown.

I have found various ways to create a timer, most successfully with the `time.sleep` command and a `while` loop.

However, the user needs to be able to input a word whilst the timer is going on, otherwise the user could take as long as they want to think of their word after the timer has stopped. Once the timer has stopped, whatever the user has typed in should be taken as their word. I haven't found any kind of solution for this yet as python runs sequentially so it's difficult to have a timer and an input at the same time.

Comment: I think you need to use threads [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm) may be useful

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run a background timer in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002497/how-to-run-a-background-timer-in-python)

Comment: The problem with threading suggestions is, you can't easily terminate a "waiting for input" thread from a "watches the clock" thread.

Comment: @Kevin the duplicate I linked addresses how to do that, it's trying to solve a similar problem.

Comment: Are you trying to write a console app, or a GUI?

Comment: Do you want [raw_input and timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3471461/4279)? (the best solutions are platform dependant, what is your OS?) If you are using a GUI framework; there is usually a builtin way to do it (specific calls are different but the principle is the same).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me previously... Uses time.time(). If this isn't what you are looking for maybe check out perf_counter()

```
import msvcrt
import time

def Countdown():
    p = 3.00
    alarm = time.time() + p
    text = []
    while True:
        n = time.time()
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            text.append(msvcrt.getche())    
        if n < alarm:
            print(round(alarm - n))
        else:
            print("Time's up!")
            break

Countdown()
```

[Making a countdown timer with Python and Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596988/making-a-countdown-timer-with-python-and-tkinter)

Comment: Ok, but how can he, at the same time, use `raw_input` or `input` to get a response from the user, while this is running?

Comment: Well anything within the while loop should execute until time runs out. So I would add the input feature in the while loop, probably within     if n < alarm:

Comment: Ok, but then `input` will block, and no other code will execute until the user enters some text and presses Enter. So they could wait a million seconds before pressing enter, and your script wouldn't print "Time's up" until after that million seconds.

Comment: Ah you are right. Instead maybe he could add an if statement to see if there is a key press is waiting to be read in using msvcrt.kbhit()

Comment: @Kevin I edited the code to add that in, could you see if that makes sense?