# How to limit time user takes to input - Python

Tags: python

EDIT:
I solved this by implementing [@L3viathan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107455/how-to-limit-time-user-takes-to-input-python/35107490#35107490). Here is the updated code:

```
import operator
import random
from time import time
import sys

def menu():
    menu = input("\n\n\n--------\n  Menu  \n--------\nPress:\n- (1) to play \n- (2) to exit\n: ")
    if menu == "1":
        play_game()
    if menu == "2":
        print("Exiting...")
        sys.exit()
    while menu != "1" or menu != "2":
        print("Please enter a valid choice")
        menu = input("--------\n  Menu  \n--------\nPress:\n- (1) to play \n- (2) to exit\n: ")
        if menu == "1":
            play_game()
        if menu == "2":
            print("Exiting...")
            break

def game_over():
    print("Game over.")
    file = open("score.txt", "r")
    highscore = file.read()
    if int(highscore) < score:
        file = open("score.txt", "w")
        file.write(score)
        file.close()
        print("Score: {}\n\n******************\nNew highscore!\n******************".format(str(score)))
    else:
        print("Score: {}\nHighscore: {}".format(str(score), str(highscore)))

def play_game():
    print("Type in the correct answer to the question\nYou have 3 seconds to answer each question\nThe game will continue until you answer a question incorrectly") #displays the welcome message
    counter = 1 
    score = 0

    while counter == 1:
        ops = {"+":operator.add, 
                "-":operator.sub,
                "x":operator.mul} 
        num1 = random.randint(0, 10) 
        op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
        num2 = random.randint(1, 10) 
        print("\nWhat is {} {} {}? ".format(num1, op, num2))
        start = time()
        guess = float(input("Enter your answer: "))
        stop = time()
        answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)

        if guess == answer:
            if stop - start > 3:
                print("You took too long to answer that question. (" + str(stop - start) + " seconds)")
                def game_over():
                    print("Game over.")
                    file = open("score.txt", "r")
                    highscore = file.read()
                    if int(highscore) < score:
                        file = open("score.txt", "w")
                        file.write(score)
                        file.close()
                        print("Score: {}\n\n******************\nNew highscore!\n******************".format(str(score)))
                    else:
                        print("Score: {}\nHighscore: {}".format(str(score), str(highscore)))
                    menu()
                game_over()
                break
            else:
                score = score + 1 
                print("Correct!\nScore: " + str(score))
        else: 
            print("Game over.")
            counter = counter - 1
            file = open("score.txt", "r")
            highscore = file.read()
            if int(highscore) < score:
                file = open("score.txt", "w")
                file.write(score)
                file.close()
                print("Score: {}\n\n******************\nNew highscore!\n******************".format(str(score)))
            else:
                print("Score: {}\nHighscore: {}".format(str(score), str(highscore)))
        if counter != 1:
            menu()
menu()
```

Thank you all for your contributions.

------ EDIT END -------

I have been searching Stack Overflow for a solution however I could not find anything which works with my game, therefore I appologise if this is a duplicate question.

I am making a math game where a user has to answer a simple arithmetic question, each time the user enters the correct answer, the score increases by one. However, if the user enters a wrong answer, the game ends.

I would like to add a timeout feature to the game, for example when a user is entering an answer to one of the questions, if the user takes more than 3 seconds to answer, the game ends. Does anyone know how to do this?

All of the solutions I could find were for Unix, not Windows.

Here is my code:

```
import operator
import random

def play_game():
    print("Type in the correct answer to the question\nYou have 3 seconds to answer each question\nThe game will continue until you answer a question incorrectly") #displays the welcome message
    counter = 1 
    score = 0

    while counter == 1:
        ops = {"+":operator.add, 
                "-":operator.sub,
                "x":operator.mul} 
        num1 = random.randint(0, 10) 
        op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
        num2 = random.randint(1, 10) 
        print("\nWhat is {} {} {}? ".format(num1, op, num2))
        guess = float(input("Enter your answer: "))
        answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)

        if guess == answer: 
            score = score + 1 
            print("Correct!\nScore: " + str(score)) 
        else: 
            print("Game over.")
            counter = counter - 1
            file = open("score.txt", "r")
            highscore = file.read()
            if int(highscore) < score:
                file = open("score.txt", "w")
                file.write(score)
                file.close()
                print("Score: {}\n\n******************\nNew highscore!\n******************".format(str(score)))
            else:
                print("Score: {}\nHighscore: {}".format(str(score), str(highscore)))
        if counter != 1:
            menu = input("\n\n\nMenu\n----\nPress:\n- (1) to play again\n- (2) to exit\n: ")
            if menu == "1":
                play_game()
            elif menu == "2":
                print("Exiting...")
                break
            while menu != "1" or menu != "2":
                print("Please enter a valid choice")
                menu = input("Menu\n----\nPress:\n- (1) to play again\n- (2) to exit\n: ")
                if menu == "1":
                    play_game()
                elif menu == "2":
                    break
                    print("Exiting...")
play_game()
```

Comment: What's the error? What have you tried? What's your question?

Comment: What you want is a thread

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sorry?

Comment: input blocks so the game won't end after 3 seconds it will potentially block forever.

Comment: @PadraicCunninghum could you give an example?

Comment: I will throw something together for you later

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002497/how-to-run-a-background-timer-in-python/26002647#26002647

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to time the call to `input`:

```
from time import time

start = time()
answer = input("Answer this in 3 seconds: 1 + 1 = ")
stop = time()

if stop - start < 3:
    if answer == "2":
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
else:
    print("Too slow")
```

This way is simple, but you couldn't abort the user's ability to input after three seconds, only wait for it and then see if it was fast enough.

Comment: No he want's you to only have 3 seconds before `input` returns.

Comment: @Matt According to their edit, they seem to be happy with this solution, but I also thought of that. I think it is probably not worth the effort, but if you submit an answer that solves it that way, I'd consider that the better answer as well..