# How to use the threading module to call a function?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading

Or in other words, how to create a time delayed function?
I have a python bot that is supposed to send notifications to user's followers upon the usage of certain commands.

For example , if Tim runs the command  ' >follow Tom ', all of Tim's followers will be notified in PM's that he followed Tom , and Tom will be notified that Tim followed him.

I have tested this function with a large amount of followers , and the bot remains stable and avoids being kicked from the server , i'm guessing because the for loop adds a delay to each message sent to each follower.

The problem I have is if two user's were to simultaneously run a command that warrant's a notification. The bot gets kicked offline immediately. So what I need is to add an artificial delay before the notification function is run.
Time.sleep() , does not work. all it does it freeze the entire program , and hold every command in a queue. (If two user's ran >follow , it would sleep for 2 seconds , and just run both their commands after the delay)

I'm trying to use the threading module in order to replace time.sleep(). My notification function is the following.

```
#message is the message to be sent, var is the username to use
def notify(message,var):
      #SQL connect 
      dbconfig = read_db_config()
      conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
      cursor = conn.cursor()
      #choose all of user's followers
      cursor.execute('select username from users where notifications=0 and username IN (select follower from followers where followed like "{}")'.format(var))
      results = cursor.fetchall()
      #for each , send a PM
      for result in results:
        self.pm.message(ch.User(str(result[0])), message)
      conn.close()
```

So how would I use threading to do this? I've tried a couple ways , but let's just go with the worst one.

```
def example(_):
    username = 'bob'
    # _ is equal to args
    a = notify("{} is now following {}.".format(username,_),username)
    c =threading.Timer(2,a)
    c.start()
```

This will throw a Nonetype error in response.

> Exception in thread Thread-1: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
>       self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Note: I **think** this method will work , there will be a lot of users using the bot at once, so until it breaks this seems like a fix.

Comment: Anything in [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/474528/2823755) that might help: or [Run certain code every n seconds (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3393612/2823755); or [How to execute a function asynchronously every 60 seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223157/2823755) ...

Comment: hmmm... these are using time.sleep which really doesn't seem to work for me.. also remember it's a bot , so when it's in time.sleep(), all it does is freeze the bot and not allow it to be used. And the requests just pile up. I need any other requests to have to wait until the time is over , before their delay starts.

Comment: Instead of having `notify()` write the message directly by calling `self.pm.message()`, have it write the message to a queue.  Have another thread that is reads from that queue, waits some delay, then actually sends the message.

Comment: in other words , in the for loop , for each user found , put each result in a queue , and create a delay for each? would i still use threading for that or another module ?

Comment: What are the errors you're getting? It looks like maybe you need a mutex possibly?

Comment: Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1082, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Notice that you arent passing a callable to [Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) but the result of the function which is `None` in this case, in order for this to work you could do `from functools import partial` `a = partial(notify, "{} is now following {}}.".format(username,_),username)` so you are actually passing it a callable which will get called 2 second later.

Comment: It might be worth a look at [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#new-coroutine-declaration-syntax) if you're using python 3.6

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code that may help.  Notice the change to how `notify` handles the results.

```
import threading
import Queue

def notifier(nq):
    # Read from queue until None is put on queue.
    while True:
        t = nq.get()
        try:
            if t is None:
                break
            func, args = t
            func(*args)
            time.sleep(2) # wait 2 seconds before sending another notice
        finally:
            nq.task_done()


# message is the message to be sent, var is the username to use, nq is the
# queue to put notification on.
def notify(message, var, nq):
    #SQL connect
    dbconfig = read_db_config()
    conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #choose all of user's followers
    cursor.execute('select username from users where notifications=0 and username IN (select follower from followers where followed like "{}")'.format(var))
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    #for each , send a PM
    for result in results:
        # Put the function to call and its args on the queue.
        args = (ch.User(str(result[0])), message)
        nq.put((self.pm.message, args))
    conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start a thread to read from the queue.
    nq = Queue.Queue()
    th = threading.Thread(target=notifier, args=(nq,))
    th.daemon = True
    th.start()
    # Run bot code
    # ...
    #
    nq.put(None)
    nq.join() # block until all tasks are done
```

Comment: The gap you put under th.start() is supposed to be the rest of the bot code?

Comment: It would be where you would call/start whatever body of code is calling `notify()`.  This could all be put into another startup/initialization function, but is here in the main section as an example.  The point is to start up the handler thread first, before running the rest of the bot code.

Comment: ok , it seems i will still need a delay , because it reads through the Queue and still kicks the bot after many requests

Comment: @Pacified - Fixed answer to include delay

Comment: so that added a delay between each message and the delay added up , i got no response from the bot for like 30 seconds. and then it sent all the requests at once and got kicked.

Comment: Seems like there is more going on, like something is batching up the messages and then sending them all at once (even if there is a delay between calling `self.pm.message()`).  Is there some way to flush pending messages?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a threading lock like the class I wrote below.

This will cause only one thread to be able to send PM's at any given time.

```
class NotifyUsers():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.notify_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.dbconfig = read_db_config()
        self.conn = MySQLConnection(**dbconfig)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def notify_lock_wrapper(self, message, var):
        self.notify_lock.acquire()
        try:
            self._notify(message, var)
        except:
            # Error handling here
            pass
        finally:
            self.notify_lock.release()

    def _notify(self, message, var):
        #choose all of user's followers
        self.cursor.execute('select username from users where notifications=0 and username IN (select follower from followers where followed like "{}")'.format(var))
        results = self.cursor.fetchall()

        #for each, send a PM
        for result in results:
            self.pm.message(ch.User(str(result[0])), message)
```